# How can i check type of object?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - Determine the type of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/python-determine-the-type-of-an-object)

I want 'complex' to be printed, but nothing happend, why? How to do this right?

```
>>> c = (5+3j)
>>> type(c)
<type 'complex'>
>>> if type(c) == 'complex': print 'complex'
... 
>>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(c, complex):
```

From the documentation:

> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof. Also return true if classinfo is a type object (new-style class) and object is an object of that type or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.

Comment: i start from python tutorial, but have some questions before they are explained, thank You

Comment: Before using this everywhere, you might wish to read [`isinstance()` considered harmful](http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/).

Comment: if this is important i will read it

Answer (score 2):

Try `if isinstance(c,complex): print 'complex'`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> c = 5+3j
>>> c
(5+3j)
>>> type(c)
<type 'complex'>
>>> complex
<type 'complex'>
>>> type(c) == complex
True
>>> isinstance(c, complex)
True
>>>
```

`type(c) == complex` would mean "this is definitely an instance of `complex`, not some subclass".  `isinstance(c, complex)` would include subclasses.

Comment: good to know about this, thank You