# How to identify a "NoSuchObject" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysnmp

I'm currently working on a SNMP module in Python 3 (Python 3.1.3) based on PySnmp to easily send GET/WALK SNMP queries from other programs. This is mainly for fun/learning.

When querying an existing OID, I get a tuple such as :

```
(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.1.7.0), Integer(72))
```

which I can read using a "for" construct.

However, when querying a non-existing OID (which is what I do for unit testing), I get :

```
(ObjectName(2.3.4.5.6.7.8), NoSuchObject('b'''))
```

How can I differentiate the "normal" case, where the 2nd element of the tuple is an integer/string/(other?) and the "error" case where this 2nd element is a 'NoSuchObject' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like here [Determine the type of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/python-determine-the-type-of-an-object)

```
type(your_tuple[1]) == NoSuchObject
```

or

```
isinstance(your_tuple[1], NoSuchObject)
```

Comment: When I tried these, it failed miserably :

`NameError: global name 'NoSuchObject' is not defined`

Then I realized my code had no clue what 'NoSuchObject' was. It worked like a charm after I did :

`from pysnmp.proto.rfc1905 import NoSuchObject`

Got it, thx !

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to match ASN.1 types of noSuchObject and the value part of SNMP response var-bind tuple:

```
>>> from pysnmp.proto import rfc1905
>>> rfc1905.noSuchObject.isSameTypeWith(rfc1905.noSuchObject)
True
>>> rfc1905.noSuchObject.isSameTypeWith(rfc1905.noSuchInstance)
False
>>> rfc1905.noSuchObject.isSameTypeWith(varBind[1]) # varBind from SNMP response
False
```