# How can I determine the type of an argument passed in python

Tags: python

Specifically I want to know which properties are available on `myFile` in the following code sample:

```
def upload(self, myFile):
    out = """<html>
    <body>
        myFile length: %s<br />
        myFile filename: %s<br />
        myFile mime-type: %s
    </body>
    </html>"""

    # Although this just counts the file length, it demonstrates
    # how to read large files in chunks instead of all at once.
    # CherryPy reads the uploaded file into a temporary file;
    # myFile.file.read reads from that.
    size = 0
    while True:
        data = myFile.file.read(8192)
        if not data:
            break
        size += len(data)

    return out % (size, myFile.filename, myFile.content_type)
upload.exposed = True
```

This is taken from the CherryPy file upload example, and it shows a couple of the properties available in the documentation.  Namely `file`, `filename`, `content_type`

But how can I determine all the properties, or better what the actual type is so I can open the source and read the properties?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Determine the type of an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/python-determine-the-type-of-an-object)

Comment: You could use `hasattr(object, name)` to see if name exist in object. Or simply try and catch a `AttributeError` exception. But maybe you could find an other way to be sure which properties you get (by having a stronger data model object for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type can be obtained with `type(myFile)`. You can use `inspect` module or `myFile.__dict__` to see properties.

If you want to see the source code, use `type(myFile).__module__` to see where it is defined.