# Correct way to check if Pandas DataFrame index is a certain type (DatetimeIndex)

Tags: python, pandas

In the code below I want to check if the `index` in the dataframes is of type `DatetimeIndex`. Is this a correct way of doing this? Is there a better way to do this than with the `if` statement? It seems straight-forward, but wonder if I'm missing something.

I want to do this because I foresee that users occassionally may not read in the `data` with the corresponding date information.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'x' : [1,2,3],
    'y' : [4,5,6]}

index = pd.date_range("2014-1-1", periods=3, freq="D")
```

Case 1

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
type(df.index) == pd.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
```

Correctly returns: `False`

Case 2

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)
type(df.index) == pd.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
```

Correctly returns: `True`

Thanks in advance. And I hope that this isn't too trivial.

Comment: or you can do `isinstance(df.index, pd.DatetimeIndex)`

Comment: actually if you KNOW its an index, you can do ``index.is_all_dates``

Comment: @joris thanks for the information. Am I correct in assuming that these are preferable because they are more concise or are there other reasons?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python

Answer (score 13):

As of 2021, here is the up to date way of checking this:

```py
>>> df.index.inferred_type == "datetime64"
>>> True
```

So you could add something like this into your application:

```py
assert df.index.inferred_type == 'datetime64', "must have a datetime index"
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The more robust way is to use `pandas.api.types`, e.g. `ptypes.is_datetime64_any_dtype`.

For example,

```
import pandas.api.types as ptypes

ptypes.is_datetime64_dtype(df.index)
ptypes.is_numeric_dtype(df.index)
ptypes.is_string_dtype(df.index)
```

It's related to this answer for column types: [Asserting column(s) data type in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596493/asserting-columns-data-type-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

As I found out from [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python) (mentioned in the comment by @joris) and other sources, there are several ways to do it, although each of them will be useful for a specific case.

In my case, I tried to create own function to show the information about a DataFrame or a Series, depends on input parameters.

When you run `type(df.index)` you'll get an output e.g. `<class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'>` or `<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>`

'RangeIndex' can be in case you've just imported your data from CSV or other source and have not set the index for your df yet. To check it use:

```
if isinstance(df.index, pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex): print('yes')
if type(df.index) is pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex: print('yes')
```

I also played with the string output and it worked too, but it's not recommended by Python programmers, although it can be useful in a specific case:

```
if str(type(df.index)) == "<class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'>": 
    print('type of index is RangeIndex:',type(df.index))
```

In your case just use

```
if isinstance(df.index, pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex): 
    print('here I want to do something because my index is DatetimeIndex')
```

*Note*: if you imported `pandas` as `pd` in your script, use `pd.core...` in the codes above

Simple solution to get the class name of the object `df.index.__class__.__name__`

so, you can check `if df.index.__class__.__name__ == 'DatetimeIndex': 'do something'`

This answer ['type of an object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/determine-the-type-of-an-object) covers more broad usecase in Python