# Asserting column(s) data type in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assert

I'm trying to find a better way to assert the column data type in Python/Pandas of a given dataframe.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
t = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,6,0.75], 'c':['foo','bar','beer']})
```

I would like to assert that specific columns in the data frame are numeric.  Here's what I have:

```
numeric_cols = ['a', 'b']  # These will be given
assert [x in ['int64','float'] for x in [t[y].dtype for y in numeric_cols]]
```

This last assert line doesn't feel very pythonic.  Maybe it is and I'm just cramming it all in one hard to read line.  Is there a better way?  I would like to write something like:

```
assert t[numeric_cols].dtype.isnumeric()
```

I can't seem to find something like that though.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You could use `ptypes.is_numeric_dtype` to identify numeric columns, `ptypes.is_string_dtype` to identify string-like columns, and `ptypes.is_datetime64_any_dtype` to identify datetime64 columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.api.types as ptypes

t = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,6,0.75], 'c':['foo','bar','beer'],
              'd':pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=3)})
cols_to_check = ['a', 'b']

assert all(ptypes.is_numeric_dtype(t[col]) for col in cols_to_check)
# True
assert ptypes.is_string_dtype(t['c'])
# True
assert ptypes.is_datetime64_any_dtype(t['d'])
# True
```

---

The `pandas.api.types` module (which I aliased to `ptypes`) has both a `is_datetime64_any_dtype` and a `is_datetime64_dtype` function. The difference is in how they treat timezone-aware array-likes:

```
In [239]: ptypes.is_datetime64_any_dtype(pd.DatetimeIndex([1, 2, 3], tz="US/Eastern"))
Out[239]: True

In [240]: ptypes.is_datetime64_dtype(pd.DatetimeIndex([1, 2, 3], tz="US/Eastern"))
Out[240]: False
```

Comment: @Mr.F. You're right; thanks. But since I'm going for clarity, not winning code golf, I've changed it to `['a', 'b']`.

Comment: The reason I do not want to use `for col in 'ab'` is because it does not generalize to the case of multi-character column names. Of course, you could say the same about `for col in list('ab')`. (Sometimes, however, `list('ab')` is useful where `'ab'` is not -- consider `pd.DataFrame(..., index=list('ab'))` for instance.) In any case, since most people coming to this page are going to have multi-character column names, we might as well write code that generalizes easily to that case.

Comment: Is there anything similar to is_numeric_dtype for strings (or objects, in pandas terminology)?

Comment: @famargar: You could use `ptypes.is_string_dtype`. I've edited the post above to show what I mean.

Comment: Thanks, this is great!

Comment: and what about datetime columns?

Comment: @famargar: You could use `ptypes.is_datetime64_any_dtype`. See above. (I found this by perusing `dir(ptypes)`.)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this

```
import numpy as np
numeric_dtypes = [np.dtype('int64'), np.dtype('float64')]
# or whatever types you want

assert t[numeric_cols].apply(lambda c: c.dtype).isin(numeric_dtypes).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Example how to simple do python's **isinstance** check of column's panda dtype where column is numpy datetime:

```
isinstance(dfe.dt_column_name.dtype, type(np.dtype('datetime64')))
```

note: dtype could be checked against list/tuple as 2nd argument.

If you're interested in checking column's data type consistency over rows then @ely answer using apply could be better choice