# Distinguishing between HTML and non-HTML pages in Scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-crawler, scrapy

I am building a Spider in Scrapy that follows all the links it can find, and sends the url to a pipeline. At the moment, this is my code:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapyTest.items import TestItem
import urlparse


class TestSpider(Spider):
name = 'TestSpider'
allowed_domains = ['pyzaist.com']
start_urls = ['http://pyzaist.com/drone']

def parse(self, response):
    item = TestItem()
    item["url"] = response.url
    yield item

    links = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
    for link in links:
        yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, link))
```

This does the job, but throws an error whenever the response is just a Response, not a TextResponse or HtmlResponse. This is because there is no Response.xpath(). I tried to test for this by doing:

```
if type(response) is TextResponse:
    links = response.xpath("//a@href").extract()
    ...
```

But to no avail. When I do that, it never enters the if statement. I am new to Python, so it might be a language thing. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer. `type()` only gives information on the immediate type. It tells nothing of inheritance. I was looking for `isinstance()`. This code works:

```
if isinstance(response, TextResponse):
    links = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
    ...
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2225066/1455074, near the bottom