# How to do type verification in python?

Tags: python

(Maybe b/c I'm from a C++ world)
I want to verify some python variable is

`list(string)` or `list(dict(int, string))` or `SomethingIterable(string)`

Is there a simple and unified way to do it?
(Instead of writing customized code to iterate and verify each instance..)

I emphasize that I understand in Python `list` can have elements of different types, which is exactly the reason why I ask how to verify a `list` which are composed by just a certain type e.g. `string`.

Comment: Have you tried `isinstance`?

Comment: `hasattr(var, "__iter__")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine the type of a Python object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/determine-the-type-of-a-python-object)

Comment: when you say list, do you actually need a list, or an iterable, or a subscriptable, or both?

Comment: So I think everyone is showing this is the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): Why do you want to do type verification? Python is an [EAFP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) language

Answer (score 4):

In Python lists can be composed of mixed types, there is no way to do something like setting the "type" of a list. Also, even if you could, this "type" is not enforced and could change at any time.

Comment: This. `["Hi", 0, count()]` is a valid list in python.

Comment: Note: As a rule, `list`s _should_ typically be of homogeneous type. But yeah, it's completely unenforced/unenforceable; we're all adults, and if you want to do terrible things with `list`s, that's between you, your conscience, and the pitchfork wielding mobs of programmers who have to read/maintain your code later. `tuple` is either homogeneous (if being used logically as an immutable `list`), or heterogeneous (when being used logically as a "lightweight object"; e.g. any case where `collections.namedtuple` might be appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for an array ([`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)), not a list:

```
>>> l = [1]
>>> l.append('a')
>>> import array
>>> a = array.array('l')
>>> a.append(3)
>>> a.append('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
>>> a
array('l', [3])
```

As you get more and more comfortable with Python, though, you will gradually learn how to structure your code in such a way that type-checking becomes unnecessary. Personally, I've never had to use an `array.array` in Python (except in cases like this, where I'm specifically working with that module).

Answer (score -3):

Use the [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module

Typically:

```
from typing import List

def method(value: List[str]):
    pass
```

Comment: That's type annotation, but it's purely for static analysis; it performs no checking at all either at compile or run time.

Comment: that's still a start, though.