# Preventing a Python For-loop from iterating over a single string by char

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, for-loop

I have a variable which can be a single string or a list of string. When the variable is a single string , the loop iterates it by char.

```
text = function() # the function method can return a single string or list of string
for word in text:
    print word+"/n"
# When it is a single string , it prints char by char.
```

I would want the loop to iterate only one time when it is a single string. I actually do not want to use other loop types. How can I do it with for each structure?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/determine-the-type-of-a-python-object like this?

Comment: What about checking type of `text`?

Comment: in the case of a single string you could just return [yourstring] as a list consisting of a single element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would be cleaner if your function would always return a list even one with only one element. I would highly recommend this if you can change your code there.

Otherwise add this line before your loop:

```
text = text if isinstance(text, list) else [text]
```

Also your variable names are confusing you should call "text" "word_list" or something just to better indicate the type required.

Requiring type checking usually indicates a problem of style.

Comment: Thx, obviously, the lists confused me here:)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
text = function() 
if isinstance(text, list):
    for word in text:
        print word + "/n"
else:
    print text + "/n"
```

Comment: This is not a pythonic way of doing things, since if `function()` returns a tuple of strings then you're code would attempt to print the entire tuple as one word.

Comment: From the question, it is obvious that function returns either string or list of strings... Not a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

I settled on this because it puts an emphasis on preparation for a loop rather than a fundamental loop (re)design:

```
if type(thing) is str:
    x = [thing]
elif type(thing) is list:
    x = thing[:]

for i in x:
   ... do stuff ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite duck typing being the norm, sometimes you simply must check the type of something. In this case, you expect something of instance `basestring`.

```
text = function()
if isinstance(text, basestring):
    print text
else:
    for word in text:
        print word
```

Comment: `basestring` is python2 only

Comment: @tacaswell "python-2.7" tag

Comment: won't let me change my vote anymore.  Better to use `six` or `pies`.

Comment: Also `print` statement in code, so you'll need a `print_function` import. We must have read different questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) method to check the type of value hold by your variable which as per document:

> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.

Using that you may create your custom function as:

```
import collections

def my_print(my_val):
    if isinstance(my_val, str):
        print my_val
    elif isinstance(my_val, collections.Iterable):  # OR, use `list` if you just want check for list object
        # To check object is iterable ^
        for val in my_val:
            print val
    else:
       raise TypeError('Unknown value')
```

Sample run:

```
>>> my_print('Hello')
Hello
>>> my_print(['Hello', 'World'])
Hello
World
```

---

`instance()` checks whether the object passed is the instance of passed class or not.

```
>>> isinstance('hello', str)
True
>>> isinstance('hello', list)
False
```

Alternatively, you may check for the type of variable using [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) as:

```
>>> type('hello') == str
True
```

Comment: This will fail with `tuples`

Comment: @tacaswell: Thanks for the comment. Updated it

Comment: You only really need to special case `str` and let duck typing take care of the rest.

Comment: I am handling it explicitly for cases when `int` or any other value is passed to the function

Answer (score 0):

Still doable by duck typing, you just need to use a method on a list that is not in a string or vice versa, and catch the exception, for example `copy()` is a method of list but not str.

```
text = function()
try:
    temp_text = text.copy()
    for word in text:
        print word
except AttributeError:
    print text
```

In the above code if `function()` returned a string `text.copy()` will rise an AttributeError exception and will not go through the for loop but go to the exception block and print the text as is, on the other hand if `text.copy()` is successful it means it is a list and it continues to the for loop to print each word of the list.

Comment: You could just check for the attribute instead of actually executing the method: assert(hasattr(text, 'copy')). You would get an AssertionError in case that would be false. Even though it is said that raising exceptions is better than type-checking, it would be interesting which one would perform better.