# How can I see if a list contains another list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I check to see if a list contains other lists? 
I need it so that

`[['cow'], 12, 3, [[4]]]`

would output `True`, while something like

`['cow', 12, 3, 4]`

would output `False`.

Comment: `['cow'] in lst` is all you need

Comment: Do you need to check for specific inner lists, or check if there are any inner lists at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/determine-the-type-of-a-python-object

Comment: @WilliamStern Please don't forget to mark an answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). [It seems you are using the code from my answer already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195831) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you also want to find subclasses of lists then you should use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
def any_list_in(obj):
    return any(isinstance(item, list) for item in obj)
```

[`any`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) stops as soon as the condition is `True` so this only needs to check only as many items as necessary.

```
>>> any_list_in([['cow'], 12, 3, [[4]]])
True

>>> any_list_in(['cow', 12, 3, 4])
False
```

The `isinstance(item, list) for item in obj` is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) that works similar to a `for`-loop or a list-comprehension. It could also be written as (longer and slightly slower but maybe that's better to comprehend):

```
def any_list_in(obj):
    for item in obj:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: _longer and slightly slower_ Why would it be slower?

Comment: @Gabriel Because the builtin-`any` is written in C (at least if we're talking about CPython), while the loop+`if` is "only" Python.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat solution using a list comprehension.

Given `obj = [['cow'], 12, 3, [[4]]]`, we'll first use a list comprehension to get a list of *types* in `obj`:

```
>>> [type(x) for x in obj]
[<type 'list'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'list'>]
```

Now, we simply check if `list` is in the list of types we created. Let's revisit our list comprehension and turn it into a boolean expression:

```
>>> list in [type(x) for x in obj]
```

There, that's nice and short. So does it work?

```
>>> obj = [['cow'], 12, 3, [[4]]]
>>> list in [type(x) for x in obj]
True
>>> obj = ['cow', 12, 3, 4]
>>> list in [type(x) for x in obj]
False
```

Comment: Don't call the list `input` and `type(list())` literally *is* `list`.

Comment: @Wombatz thanks for the pointer on the redundancy of `type(list())`, I updated my answer. What's the concern with the use of `input` on a code example?

Comment: It's a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) in both python2 and python3

Comment: @Wombatz Thanks for your corrections, much appreciated. I'll update the answer again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method if your list does not contain some string with '[' int it .

```
def check(a):
   a=str(a)
   if a.count('[')==1:  # or a.count(']')==1;
      return False
   return True
```

In python 2.7 we have a module for this work:( I don't know about any such module in python 3.x )

```
from compiler.ast import flatten    
def check(a):
    if flatten(a)==a:
        return False
    return True
```