# Run different class based on variable name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Let's say we have a few different classes: `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC`, and `ClassD`. I have a variable I will set based on different circumstances. I know what it will be ahead of time, but I don't want to have to rewrite many different lines of code in different files each time I need to change it. It is NOT user set.

So now we have
`Variable = ClassX`

So, Let's say I set `Variable` to `ClassA`. How can I make it call `ClassA` using just that? For example, I know I can do this:

```
Variable = ClassA
if Variable == ClassA:
     # Call ClassA and run it
elif Variable == ClassB:
     # Call ClassB and run it
elif Variable == ClassC:
     # Call ClassC and run it
elif Variable == ClassD:
     # Call ClassD and run it
```

However, I want to do something like this:

```
Variable = ClassA
V = Variable()
```

Is this possible?

EDIT:
A little more detail...

So I have 3 files that are used in this scenario.

File1.py:

```
# Class = ClassA
# Class = ClassB
Class = ClassC
# Class = ClassD
...
if Class == "ClassA":
    c = ClassSystem.ClassA
    short_name = c.get_short_name()
elif Class == "ClassB":
    c = ClassSystem.ClassB
    short_name = c.get_short_name()
elif Class == "ClassC":
    c = ClassSystem.ClassC
    short_name = c.get_short_name()
elif Class == "ClassD":
    c = ClassSystem.ClassD
    short_name = c.get_short_name()
...
```

File2.py:

```
from Folder.File1 import short_name
from Folder.ClassSystem import *
...
S = short_name()
S.get_information()
```

This doesn't seem to work. File2 is referencing the variable from file1. I then need File2 to use the variable from File1 to run the same class in ClassSystem.

Comment: yes, that is totally possible. Have you tried it?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/determine-the-type-of-an-object

Comment: @NilsWerner I have added more information. It doesn't seem to work in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, completely possible. Instead of doing it with `if`s though, the most compact approach would include a dictionary of class names to class objects.

You can then key the dictionary and call the resulting class:

```
cls_dict = {c.__name__: c for c in {ClassA, ClassB}}
v = 'ClassA'
cls_dict[v]()
```

the set of classes can, of course, be altered to include any additional objects you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`,

```
c_name = 'ClassA'
obj = eval(c_name)()
```

but i am not sure if `eval` is the recommended way to do this.