# Proper way to typecheck object parameter

Tags: python

This code does not seem to work:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,color):
        assert type(color) == 'str', 'Must be string'
        self.color = color

dog = Dog('black')


line 26, in __init__ assert type(color) == 'str', 'Must be string'
AssertionError: Must be string
```

Even though I've used a string. Is their a way to check if a given argument has the correct type?

Comment: `type(color) == str`, not `type(color) == 'str'`. Also, check [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine the type of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/determine-the-type-of-an-object)

Comment: I feel it is important to mention that this is probably unidiomatic. Also, `assert` should really only be used for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

First, `'str'` and `str` are different: the first one is a string, and the second one is the `str` class. If you compare with the class, `(type('hello') == str) is True`.

You most likely want to check if the argument is an instance of `str`:

```
assert isinstance(color, str), 'Must be string'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check types, without using `isinstance`, this is your alternative.

```
assert type(color) == type(""), 'Must be string'
```

or

```
assert type(color) == str, 'Must be string'
```

Comment: why not just `type(color) == str`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo correct, editing my answer

Comment: @Tomerikoo `type()`and `isinstance()`are not the same thing. (https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549801/11301900)

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I am well aware of that. My point was: considering the code present is `type(color) == type("")`, you might as well write `type(color) == str`. Whether that is the correct approach or not, I didn't claim to state. Simply an obvious fix

Comment: @Tomerikoo My apologies, somehow I thought you were the author of this answer.