# Function that takes 1 iterable parameter and adds all objects in the list if they are int or float?

Tags: python

I need to create a function that takes one iterable parameter and adds all of the objects in the list if they are an int or float. Objects that are not int or float should be skipped and a sum of int and float should be returned.
I need to use loop and isinstance function.
If there is an input [5.3, 2, "Book", True], return float object should equal to 7.3.
So far I have:

```
def add_numbers_in_list(number_list):
    for x in number_list:
        try:
            yield float(x)
        except ValueError:
            pass
number_list = [5.3, 2, "Book", True]
print(sum(add_numbers_in_list(number_list)))
```

I'm getting 8.3 as an answer.

Comment: Hint: check the result of `float(True)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine the type of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/determine-the-type-of-an-object)

Answer (score 2):

This is because `float(True)` equals  `1`. To fix your code you can do this:

```py
def add_numbers_in_list(number_list):
    for x in number_list:
       if type(x) in [float, int]: # Change over here
          yield float(x) 


number_list = [5.3, 2, "Book", True]
print(sum(add_numbers_in_list(number_list)))
```

If you would like to store the count and return it you can use the following script:

```py
def add_numbers_in_list(number_list):
    count = 0
    for x in number_list:
       if type(x) in [float, int]:
          count += float(x) 
    return count


number_list = [5.3, 2, "Book", True]
print(add_numbers_in_list(number_list))
```

Comment: How can I get it to add within the function, so I can get a return value after the function is complete and can just print it?

Comment: @Justice Please check the answer now. Hope it helps