# How to translate JavaScript ('object') into Python?

Tags: javascript, python

I am working on converting some JavaScript code into Python.

There is an if condition in the JavaScript that looks something like:
`if (typeof f === 'object')` and then a series of actions are taken if this condition evaluates to true.

In this case `f` would be something like:
`f = { 'fields': ["user_id", "date_started", "date_ended"] }`

In this case `f` is a `dict`, but it might not always be the case.

I know that in JavaScript nearly everything is considered an object.
What would be the equivalent constraint to `object` in Python?

Comment: As you said, almost everything in JavaScript is considered an object. The only things that aren't treated as objects are primitive types such as integers, strings, booleans, etc. There are probably many types in Python that would simply be considered an object in JavaScript. Although if you're talking about types with custom properties, you should take a look at [classes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript `typeof f == 'object'` is true when all of the following is **not** true:

- `f` is `undefined`: there is no equivalent in Python
- `f` is a number, bigint or boolean: in Python this is an instance of `float` or `int`. As `bool` is a subclass of `int`, it is included.
- `f` is a string: in Python this is an instance of `str`
- `f` is a symbol: there is no equivalent in Python
- `f` is a function: in Python you can use `callable` to detect this

Caveat: `typeof null == 'object'` is true, so in Python `None` should pass the equivalent test.

So this brings us to the following test in Python:

```py
if not (callable(f) or isinstance(f, (int, float, str))):
    # it is an "object"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `type` method for getting type of variables in python:

```py
if (type(f) is dict)
```

Actually, js objects in python are dictionaries! you can see more details from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/determine-the-type-of-an-object).

Comment: What about lists? tuples? `set`? An instance of any `class`?

Comment: @trincot My answer was only for this question, although incomplete, but your answer is more complete and better :)

Comment: Even in the question it says *"In this case f is a dict, but it might not always be the case."*.

Comment: @trincot  Yes, I do admit my mistake!