# How to separate this code into multiple lines?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab.

```
4y = bio_fix_drop[['Radius_mean', 'Radius_mean', 'Texture_mean', 'perimeter_mean', 'area_mean', 'smoothness_mean', 'compactness_mean', 'concavity_mean', 'concave points_mean', 'symmetry_mean', 'fractal_dimension_mean', 'radius_se', 'texture_se', 'perimeter_se', 'area_se', 'smoothness_se', 'compactness_se', 'concavity_se', 'concave points_se', 'symmetry_se', 'fractal_dimension_se', 'radius_worst', 'texture_worst', 'perimeter_worst', 'area_worst', 'smoothness_worst', 'compactness_worst', 'concavity_worst', 'concave points_worst', 'symmetry_worst', 'fractal_dimension_worst', 'diagnosis']]
```

I tried to use

```
print(4y)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to print out each element of the list into separate lines? What is the expected result/output?

Comment: I want to display the principal components and explained variance. But when I try to run the code the "y" have an error and mentions that I need to create a newline or semicolon

Comment: That `4y` line doesn't even look like valid Python. What is the type of `bio_fix_drop`? Is `4y` supposed to be a list?

Comment: bio_fix_drop represents the data used in the google colab. Even I don't know what 4y is, I just found some references on google. Really appreciate you trying to help me.

Comment: You can check an object's type by doing `print(type(bio_fix_drop))` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2225038/2745495)). Because the code `bio_fix_drop[[...]]` looks...wrong. Please also [edit] in the exact error messages that you are getting, because "*I need to create a newline or semicolon*" now is unclear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.