# How to compare these 2 python tuple of tuples of unequal length and output another tuple based on the comparison?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I have this tuple of tuples;

```
Tup1= ( ('AAA', 2), ('BBB', 3) )
```

I have another tuple;

```
Tup2 = ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD')
```

I want to compare `Tup1` and `Tup2`. Based on the comparison, I want to create another tuple of tuples that look like this;

```
OutputTup = ( ('AAA', 2), ('BBB', 3), ('CCC', 0), ('DDD', 0) )
```

The logic is like this. Look into every element inside Tup2 and then look for matching element in Tup1. If there is matching element(example 'AAA') in Tup1, copy to OutputTup ('AAA', 2). If there is no matching element (example 'CCC'), then assign a value of 0 and append to OutputTup ('CCC', 0).

How can this be done in Python 2.7? Thanks.

Comment: Please, show your attempt to solve it, so we can help in any specific problem you may have.

Comment: Ok. Doing it right now. Hold on. Stuck for some time.

Comment: what happens if there is an element in tup1 but not in tup2?

Comment: @yoopoo: it will be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This also works with the output you want:

```
tup1 = ( ('AAA', 2), ('BBB', 3) )
tup2 = ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD')
dic = dict( tup1 )
for tri in tup2:
    dic[tri] = dic.get(tri,0)

print tuple(dic.items()) 
#(('AAA', 2), ('BBB', 3), ('CCC', 0), ('DDD', 0))
```

Comment: It was quite brilliant to convert the tuple into a dictionary. I got stuck trying to use a while loop to do the comparison for each element in the tuple. Upvoted!

Comment: this will not keep the original information if there are duplicates in the first values

Comment: @yoopoo: Thanks. Elegant and easy to understand. Voted as the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

for some extend .please edit my answer . i cannot figure how to check type. if some one know feel free to edit my answer

```
from itertools import izip,izip_longest
Tup1= ( ('AAA', 2), ('BBB', 3) )
Tup2 = ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD')
lis=[ i if type(i[0])==type(0) else i[0] for i in list(izip_longest(Tup1, Tup2 , fillvalue=0))]



#output [('AAA', 2), ('BBB', 3), (0, 'CCC'), (0, 'DDD')]
```

Comment: Thanks. Although it is not the answer as the output tuple is not exactly what is wanted, I learnt something new about itertools. Upvoted.

Comment: Use type? Not sure if this is right.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-the-variable-type-in-python

Comment: nataraj Сундар : thank you for the answer. Your answer is also correct but I am sorry I can only vote for only 1 right answer. I chose the other answer because it does not need to import from another module. It is also easier for me to understand.