# What am I missing in understanding round() function?

Tags: python, rounding, built-in

I was looking at the [online doc for `round()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round) in python, which says,

> `round(number[, ndigits])`
>
> ....The return value is an integer if called with one argument, otherwise of the same type as number.

So, I wrote the below code.

```
x = round(32.7)
print 'x is now : ', x
print str(type(x))
print type(x).__name__
```

Let me explain the last two prints I used in above snippet.

1. The second print is through trial-and-error method. (Today is my Day 1 for Python)
2. The third print is added referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/402704/2173917).

Surprisingly, the **current** output is

> x is now :  33.0
> <type 'float'>
>  float

I was **expecting**

> x is now :  33
> <type 'int'>
>  int

I'm out of ideas. What am I missing?

P.S. For anybody interested, a <kbd>[LIVE VERSION](http://ideone.com/Na9xP2)</kbd>

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: You're using python 2, but referring to the python 3 documentation.

Comment: @wim Indeed, a noobie mistake. 2.7 it is.

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/tRip5P) is your code running as you expect with python 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python 2.x, [`round`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round) always returns a float.

Judging by the syntax of your print statements, you're on python 2.x.

Comment: if you don't mind, one additional Q, is the second and third print statements are in correct syntax?

Comment: @SouravGhosh For Python 2, yes. For Python 3, no.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo As of now, I'm staring with 2.7, so I'll _assume_ I'm going correct. :-) BTW, (_asking ahead of time_) what would be the correct one in 3.X?

Comment: @SouravGhosh `print` is a function in 3, so `print("hello world")`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using round...!try this because round function is to round-off the float values..

However round and type-casting to int both do same work @ background

Hope this helps..!!

```
x = int(32.7)
print 'x is now :',x
print str(type(x))
print type(x).__name__
```

or

```
y=32.7
x=int(y)
print 'x is now :',x
print str(type(x))
print type(x).__name__
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was actually experimenting with `round()` itself. Nevertheless, appreciate your effort :-)

Comment: its okay..all the best