# If statement looking for float is not working

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm learning Python, and I wrote a simple script that creates a list of tasks I need to do today. After putting an input on the task to be done, I have the script ask how long it will take to do that task. It would work in adding the float to a variable called "totaltime" but if you entered a word, it would crash, so I created an if else statement looking for if the user entered an integer and float and if they didn't, have them repeat the process. For some reason when I run it, it can't see if the input is a float or integer, it just moves on the else statement and repeats it. Please help! I've been scouring the internet and can't find a solution. I added the issue part of the script so that's its easier to read (and the totaltime variable)

```
totaltime = float()

    while True:
        print("How long will this task take?")          
        new_time = input("> ")

    if new_time == int or new_time == float:
        totaltime = float(totaltime) + float(new_time)
        break

    else: 
        print("You must enter a valid number, written as (H.M).")
```

Comment: (More discussions on type checking in Python, how to do it, and whether it's necessary at all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-the-variable-type-in-python )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking type, you should just do the conversion in a `try`/`except` block.

```
totaltime = 0.0

while True:
    try:     
        new_time = float(input("How long will this task take?\n> "))
        totaltime += new_time
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("You must enter a valid number, written as (H.M).")
```

Your attempt to check type is flawed anyway. The return value from `input` will always be `string`.

If you did want to check type, you should use `isinstance`

e.g.

```
if isinstance(new_time, (int, float)):
```

But your code is actually testing the type `int` or `float` against the **value** of `new_time`. Which will always be wrong.

Comment: thank you! I forgot about the try statement... excellent answer! May I ask, what is the difference between "new_time = float(new_time)" and "new_time=float()" like I'm not sure why you plug the variable back in, is that required?

Comment: When using `new_time = float(new_time)`, `new_time` starts out life a string with the value you input (e.g. "2.5"). Calling `float` converts it to a float and assigns it back to the same variable. `new_time=float()` just creates a float variable, which by default is assigned the value 0.0.