# How to print types within a list

Tags: python, list, types

So I was given a list and I must print the type of each item in the list. I can clearly see that there are strings and integers but I need it to print out in Python. We just learned **for loops** so I feel like that is what they are looking for but I cannot get it to print out.

Comment: check any python tutorial, You should able to do yourself

Comment: so this is the list: several_things = ["hello", 2, 4, 6.0, 7.5, 234352354, "the end", "", 99] and i used **for aseveral_thing in several_things:** and then the next line I used **print type aseveral_thing** they did something like this in our lecture but I am very new at it and am not sure if it still works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine a Python variable's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-a-python-variables-type)

Answer (score 14):

```
ls = [type(item) for item in list_of_items]
print(ls)
```

Answer (score 10):

Essentially, the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function takes an object and returns the type of it. Try the below code:

```
for item in [1,2,3, 'string', None]:
    print type(item)
```

Output:

```
<type 'int'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Answer (score 4):

use the `type` built in function of python.

```
lst = ['string', 1, 2, 'another string']
for element in lst:
   print type(element)
```

output:

```
<type 'str'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'str'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it using [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type).

```
myList = [1,1.0,"moo"]  #init the array
for i in myList: 
    print(type(i)) #loop and print the type
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = [1, 0.2, "bar"]
for i in foo:
    print(type(i))
```

Should print out the type of each item

Answer (score 1):

```
 a=[12,"string"]
 for i in a: #sets the value of a to be any item in list (a)
      print(type(a), end="   ")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
>>>  <type 'int'>    <type 'str'>
```

In the python code above type() function is used to determine the data type of variable (i). And end() is used to replace the end of the output with the value inside its' brackets () instead of a new line as you must have observed in the above output that between the 2 outputs "____ " (space) was placed without a new line.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in a solution that uses `map()` instead of `comprehensions` or `loops`:

```py
class MyClass:
   ...

def myfunc():
   ...

myint = 777
mystr = "Hello"
myobj = MyClass()

mylst = [
   MyClass, myfunc,
   myint, mystr, myobj
]

# Nice one-liner
print(*map(type, mylst), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
<class 'type'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
```