# what is the canonical way to check the type of input?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to check the type of input on the screen by using

python `types` module

I have used the `type(2) is int` for integer. ---->>>working
I have used the `type("Vivek") is str` for string. ---->>>working
 but i am confused when I take input using `raw_input()`

```
import types

p = raw_input("Enter input ")
```

if I entered string like "vivek" on `console`
then it is ok

the matter is when `int` and `float` entered

so what will be the canonical way to checked whether an input is of `boolean`,`int`,char,`string`,`long`,`byte`,`double` in `python`.

Comment: With `raw_input` you always get a bytes string of type `str` (with Python 2).

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-the-variable-type-in-python

Comment: and everything you read with `input()` in python3 is of type `str`

Comment: By the way, there is no `char` type in Python, or `byte`, or `double`...

Comment: @MKB I'm not agree. The OP ask for string conversion in Python. It's question is a little awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It up to you to convert your input to whatever you need.

But, you can guess like this:

```
import sys

p = raw_input("Enter input")

if p.lower() in ("true", "yes", "t", "y"):
    p = True
elif p.lower() in ("false", "no", "f", "n"):
    p = False
else:
    try:
        p = int(p)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            p = float(p)
        except ValueError:
            p = p.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()
```

This support `bool`, `int`, `float` and `unicode`.

Notes:

- Python has no `char` type: use a string of length 1,
- This `int` function can parse `int` values but also `long` values and even very long values,
- The `float` type in Python has a precision of a `double` (which doesn't exist in Python).

See also: [Parse String to Float or Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906)

Comment: ("true", "yes", "t", "y"): i didnt get the meaning of t y

Comment: @avkavk: It’s examples of human readable true values in English: "t" for "true", "y" for "yes". You can use your own strings.