# Validating a users input

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm using a while True loop. Inside that loop I have

```
Sentence= input("please enter a sentence").lower().split()
```

However I want to create validation so an error message appears when the user inputs a number instead of a letter. I was researching and saw the use of .isalpha. Would anyone where this would go in the whie true loop to create and error message for inputting numbers?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488787/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-the-type-of-input/39489028#39489028

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence = input("please enter a sentence").lower().split()
for word in sentence:
    if not word.isalpha():
        print("The word %s is not alphabetic." % word)
```

Comment: Thank you I completely get it! Is there a way to keep repreating the question until letters are inputted?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
sentence = input("please enter a sentence: ").lower().split()

while False in [word.isalpha() for word in sentence]:
    sentence = input("Do not use digits. Enter again: ").lower().split()
```