# Print each list element together with its datatype

Tags: python, python-2.7

The list example is

```
inList = [1.1, 2017, 3+4j, 'superbowl', (4, 5), [1,2,3,5,12],{"make":'BMW', "model":'X5'}]
```

Basically I need to write a program that iterates through a list and prints each list element together with its data type.

New to python and need help getting started. Thanks

Comment: Google? It's Python 101 question.

Comment: I was just looking for a starting point. Didn't realize it was so basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic question that you could easily answer by just looking at [the documentation about control flow](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).

```
for element in inList:
    print element, type(element)
```

Comment: For me, this didn't work in this format. Using Python 3.9. It needs to include parentheses around what you are printing: `print (element, type(element))`

Comment: @Dolunaykiz Sure, this is a very old answer based on Python 2.7 syntax. It is fairly easy to port it to Python 3, as you suggested, by including the parenthesis on the print call.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote that "I need to write a program that iterates through a list and prints each list element together with its data type."  And you were having a hard time because "I have tried google. only could find related material but nothing this specific."

Your real problem is you haven't learned to use Google to search for answers to programming questions.  The key is to break your problem down into sub-problems and search for how to solve each one:

- iterate through a list
- get data type
- print element and data type

I googled for [**python iterate through a list**](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+iterates+through+a+list&oq=python+iterates+through+a+list&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5071j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=python+iterate+through+a+list). The first result was [Exercise 32: Loops and Lists](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex32.html) from Learn Python the Hard Way which includes this code:

```
the_count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# this first kind of for-loop goes through a list
for number in the_count:
    print "This is count %d" % number
```

And this result

```
This is count 1
This is count 2
This is count 3
This is count 4
This is count 5
```

Now I googled for [**python determine data type**](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+determine+data+type&oq=python+determine+data+type&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.1352j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  The first result was Stack Overflow question [How to determine the variable type in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-the-variable-type-in-python).  Here is the relevant snippet from one of the answers:

## Use `type`

```
>>> type(one)
<type 'int'>
```

So now we know how to iterate and how to get a type.  And we see how to print, but not how to print two things at once.  Let's google for [**python print**](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+determine+data+type&oq=python+determine+data+type&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.1352j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=python+print).  The second result is [Input and Ouput](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) section of the Python 2.7 tutorial.  It turns out there are many ways to print multiple things at once, but one simple example from the page is.

```
>>> print 'We are the {} who say "{}!"'.format('knights', 'Ni')
We are the knights who say "Ni!"
```

So put this all together and we get:

```
for item in inList: 
    print '{}  {}'.format(item, type(item))
```

Which prints:

```
1.1  <type 'float'>
2017  <type 'int'>
(3+4j)  <type 'complex'>
superbowl  <type 'str'>
(4, 5)  <type 'tuple'>
[1, 2, 3, 5, 12]  <type 'list'>
{'make': 'BMW', 'model': 'X5'}  <type 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question is:

```
print map(lambda x: (x, type(x).__name__), inList)
```

Here used [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function which takes two parameters:

- Function to be applied;
- Array to be iterated.

This function iterates over every element of your array and apply given function to each of them. Results of application placed in a new array which this function return.

Also, here you can see `lambda` keyword which defines anonymous function. It takes `x` as parameter and then return pair containing this parameter and stringification of its type.