# How do I Make my String into an int in Python 3? Am I doing this wrong?

Tags: python

This seems like a problem that is easy to find on the internet, but nothing fixes the problem. I am creating a dice rolling program that lets you choose the number of dice you want to roll, but it keeps giving me an error when I type anything that's not an integer: 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10'

Here's my code:

```
print("Dice Rolling Simulator 1.0") 
def functionStart():
    diceAmount = input("How many dice would you like to roll? (we recomend less than 6): ")
    if int(diceAmount) == int:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("Please enter a number such as '3' or '7'. It is not rocket science")
        functionStart()

functionStart()
```

I'm simply trying to verify that they typed an integer. The converted number will also be used to generate the number of dice rolled later in the program. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if int(diceAmount) == int` is wrong. if not integer you'll get `ValueError`

Comment: `if int(diceAmount) == int:` what do you expect this to be doing?

Comment: ok, how do I fix it?

Comment: int(diceAmmount) casts value to integer. You do not want it. You need to check the type of variable. refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-the-variable-type-in-python

Comment: just use diceAmount.isnumeric(). this will return true if diceAmount is an integer number. False otherwise.

Comment: `def functionStart(): try: diceAmount = int( input("How many dice would you like to roll? (we recomend less than 6): ")): print("true") : catch ValueError: 
        print("Please enter a number such as '3' or '7'. It is not rocket science") :
        functionStart()

Comment: I expect "if int(diceAmount) == int:" to check if the input is an integer and not a string or float.

Comment: Use "if type(diceAmmount) is int:"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/skg99eJF

Comment: Thanks @PrateekDewan , that Fixed it.