# type of value in for loop by default in python and. how typeof is set in a loop

Tags: python

This is the sample code.

What is the type of **fruit** and **letter** in my code (whether int, list, dict, ...) when I have not declared any?

```
for letter in 'Python':    //**how letter is set to string** 
   print 'Current Letter :', letter

fruits = 1,45

for fruit in fruits:      /****/how fruit is set to int int**** 

   print 'Current fruit :', fruit
```

**output**

```
Current Letter : P
Current Letter : y
Current Letter : t
Current Letter : h
Current Letter : o
Current Letter : n
Current fruit : 1
Current fruit : 45
```

Comment: You can use the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) bultin function to get the type of any object. In your case, that would be `str` for the letters and `int` for the numbers.

Comment: before or after print use `type(letter)` and `type(fruit)` to see datatypes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the variable type in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-the-variable-type-in-python)

Comment: i have tried type(letter) it is showing no change in my output

Comment: It should write as follows <class 'str'> and <class 'int'>. The first letters are string the fruit ones are int.

Comment: You still need to print it, as in `print type(letter)`. `type` just returns the type, it can be used for other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use type() to know the type

```
for letter in 'Python':
      print 'Current Letter :', letter

fruits = 1,45

for fruit in fruits:

   print 'Current fruit :', fruit
print type(fruit)
print type(letter)
```

This will give the following output

```
Current Letter : P
Current Letter : y
Current Letter : t
Current Letter : h
Current Letter : o
Current Letter : n
Current fruit : 1
Current fruit : 45
<type 'int'>
<type 'str'>
```