# Extracting numbers from a string with xpath and python 3.6

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I couldn't apply the solution to similar questions I found here. 
After using this in visual code to scrape an web page with python and lxml

```
[...]
tree = html.fromstring(browser.page_source)
data = tree.xpath('//tr[@title="something"]/td[2]/text()')
```

if I print(data), I will get this list. Is data a list ?

```
['\n                    1.27\n                ', '\n                    1.81\n                ', '\n                    4.90\n                ', '\n
       2.07\n                ', '\n                    2.12\n                ']
```

My goal is to extract only the number from each string. I have read about a regex function, not sure if it is the solution

```
replace($MyString, '[^0-9]', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy method would be using `strip()`. you can scrub the list by doing something like:

`clean_data = [d.strip() for d in data]`

which will give you:

`['1.27', '1.81', '4.90', '2.07', '2.12']`

if you want these as actual `int`s, just use `int(d.strip())` instead

Comment: This is also exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Lets imagine that your output is stored in variable `x`:

```
>>> print("\n".join([y.strip() for y in x]))
1.27
1.81
4.90
2.07
2.12
```

Would this help? Or you need a list in which case:

```
>>> print([y.strip() for y in x])
['1.27', '1.81', '4.90', '2.07', '2.12']
```

**[UPDATE]**

As for the

> Is data a list ?

[How to determine a Python variable's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-a-python-variables-type)