# Is this some kind of array (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I'm getting with **Python** and **RPI** and there is this script in the examples for the Sense HAT emulator were I don't know what are a pair of lines of code for me they look like an array but I think they might be other kind of data, so this is the code:

```
from sense_emu import SenseHat

sense = SenseHat()

green = (0, 255, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

while True:
    humidity = sense.humidity
    humidity_value = 64 * humidity / 100
    pixels = [green if i < humidity_value else white for i in range(64)]
    sense.set_pixels(pixels)
```

What kind of data are this two ?

```
green = (0, 255, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) used to store RGB color triplets. 
You can get [information about the type of any object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-a-python-variables-type) via calling `type(obj)`.