# Iterate through list and print 'true' if list element is of a certain type

Tags: python

I was wondering if there were a way in python to loop through a list and check if a list element was of a certain type. Something like this in incorrect pseudo code.

```
listt = ['3109', datetime.timedelta(0, 240), datetime.timedelta(0, 60), '2411', 
datetime.timedelta(0, 2160), '3109']
for i in listt:
    if type(i) is class.__str__:
        print('success')
```

Is it possible to check for type like this? Also, I found myself unable to iterate through a list with timedelta objects so I've had to except a TypeError every time I encounter one. That is not shown in this code.

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: You can use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Comment: This forum might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-a-python-variables-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
for i in listt:
    if isinstance(i,str):
        print('success')
```

Output:

```
success
success
success
```

Note that your pseudo code *almost* works. The following would work as well:

```
for i in listt:
    if type(i) is str:
        print('success')
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I forgot about this.

Comment: I was getting a bit ahead of myself with the dunders.

Answer (score 3):

Another `isinstance` way:

```
for i in listt:
    print(isinstance(i,str))
```

Saved one line, but result would be:

```
True
False
False
True
False
True
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the type() function.

```
a = 3.14
if type(a) == str:
     pass
```

More information can be found here:

[How to determine a Python variable's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-a-python-variables-type)