# Comparing with type(my_function)

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, comparison

I have a function that should operate according to the type of argument passed into it, simply illustrated:

```py
def operate_according_to_type(argument_passed): 
    if type(argument_passed) == str:
        do string stuff
    elif type(argument_passed) == dict:
        do dict stuff
    elif type(argument_passed) == function:
        argument_passed()

def my_function(): pass

operate_according_to_type("Hello world")
operate_according_to_type({"foo": "bar"})
operate_according_to_type(my_function)
```

Now while `type("Hello world")`, `type({"foo": "bar"})` and `type(my_function)` will return respectively `<class 'str'>`, `<class 'dict'>` and `<class 'function'>`, I can't seem to compare to `function` just as I can to `str`, the word is not even "reserved".

How should I proceed? Should I proceed at all or is this just plain hazardous?

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009407/python-find-the-type-of-a-function/54009756#54009756

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the object is callable using the [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) built-in function:

```
...
elif callable(argument_passed):
    argument_passed()
```

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624926/how-do-i-detect-whether-a-python-variable-is-a-function).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the duplicate. Is a case like the example considered bad practice overall or is it fine?

Comment: @PierreMDL checking the type of a parameter is never a bad practice :)