# How to find inappropriate datatype in pandas data frame for each column?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

main_df:

```
    Name    Age   Id     DOB
0   Tom     20   A4565  22-07-1993
1   nick    21   G4562  11-09-1996
2   krish   AKL  F4561  15-03-1997
3   636A    18   L5624  06-07-1995
4   mak     20   K5465  03-09-1997
5   nits    55   56541  45aBc
6   444     66   NIT    09031992

column_info_df:

   Column_Name  Column_Type
0   Name         string
1   Age          integer
2   Id           string
3   DOB          Date
```

how can i find data type error value from main df. For example from column info df we can see 'Name' is a string column, so in main df, 'Name' column should contain either string or alphanumeric other than that it's an error. I need to find those datatype error values in a separate df.

error output df:

```
   Column_Name   Current_Value   Exp_Dtype   Index_No.
0  Name             444           string        6
1  Age              444           int           2
2  Name            56441          string        6
0  DOB             4aBc           Date          5
0  DOB             09031992       Date          6
```

i tried this:

```
for i,r in column_info_df.iterrows():
    if r['Column_Type'] == 'string':
          main_df[r['Column_Name']].loc[main_df[r['Column_Name']].str.match(r'[^a-z|A-Z]+')]
    elif r['Column_Type'] == 'integer':
          main_df[r['Column_Name']].loc[main_df[r['Column_Name']].str.match(r'[^0-9]+')]
    elif r['Column_Type'] == 'Date':
```

i have stuck here,because this RE is not catching every errors. i don't know how to go further?

Comment: Why would `444` be an invalid string datatype? It is valid as either a string or integer.

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/q/402504/2191572

Comment: Because string column should have atleast one alphabet .

Comment: You're not checking the datatype then, this has NOTHING to do with datatype. You are merely looking to check the data contents and whether or not they conform to certain rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of using [`df.eval()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html),

**Note**: *though this will check based on pattern and return non matching values. However, note that this cannot check valid types, example if date column has an entry which looks like a date but is an invalid date, this wouldnot identify that:*

```
d={"string":".str.contains(r'[a-z|A-Z]')","integer":".str.contains('^[0-9]*$')",
                                 "Date":".str.contains('\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d')"}
m=df.eval([f"~{a}{b}" 
   for a,b in zip(column_info_df['Column_Name'],column_info_df['Column_Type'].map(d))]).T
```

---

```
final=(pd.DataFrame(np.where(m,df,np.nan),columns=df.columns)
              .reset_index().melt('index',var_name='Column_Name',
                            value_name='Current_Value').dropna())
final['Expected_dtype']=(final['Column_Name']
                         .map(column_info_df.set_index('Column_Name')['Column_Type']))
print(final)
```

**Output**:

```
    index Column_Name Current_Value Expected_dtype
6       6        Name           444         string
9       2         Age           AKL        integer
19      5          Id         56541         string
26      5         DOB         45aBc           Date
27      6         DOB      09031992           Date
```

I agree there can be better `regex` patterns for this job but the idea should be same.

Comment: error is coming for float datatype :TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Comment: error is coming for float datatype :TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float' may be it's because of missing values, but i did exclude missing values then also it is coming this error. i tried to implement na = False in the dictionary itself. then it throwing dictionary has no attribute called 'append'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you did, you created separate dataframes, which contains infos about your main one.

What I suggest would be instead to use the build-in methods offered by pandas to deal with dataframes.

For instance, if you have a dataframe *main*, then:

```
main.info()
```

will give you the type of object for each column. Note that a column can contain only one type, as it is a series, which is itself a ndarray.

So your column *name* cannot have anything else but strings that you would have missed. Instead, you can have *NaN* values. You can check for them with the help of

```
main.describe()
```

I hope that helped :-)