# Determine if two strings differ by at most n characters

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to figure out the process in how to approach this question.

Given a list of strings (los), a string s, and an integer bound n, the function should produce True if all the strings in los are at most n characters away from s, and False otherwise.

For example,

```py
Input: (["ccat","hpat","ppat"], "ppat", 2)
```

```py
Output: True
```

and for a False case,

```py
Input: (["ccat","hpat","that"], "ppat", 1)
```

```py
Output: False
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might be looking for [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: @Sania This post is useful in this regard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-a-python-variables-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you clarified, you want to find difference between two strings by *characters with their positions*, you can do the following:

- Iterate over your list one by one.
- For each word in the list, compare it with the supplied string character by character.
- If a character from one doesn't match with the other, increment the diff counter.
- If difference becomes greater than needed difference, return `False`, else return `True`.
- Keep in mind that 2 strings in comparison can be of different lengths. Take that into account too while calculating them.

**Snippet:**

```
def isSame(str_list,s,diff_offset):
    s_len = len(s)
    for each_s in str_list:
        diff = abs(len(each_s) - s_len) # initialize with difference of string length
        length = min(len(each_s),s_len)
        for i in range(0,length):
            if s[i] != each_s[i]:
                diff = diff + 1
            if diff > diff_offset:
                return False # if difference is more than required, then return false
    return True


print(isSame(["ccat","hpat","ppat"], "ppat", 2))
print(isSame(["ccat","hpat","ppatru"], "ppat", 2))
print(isSame(["ccat","hpat","that"], "ppat", 1))
```

**Update:**

As per the problem statement, if lengths are not same, just return False before beginning to compare strings char by char.

```
def isSame(str_list,s,diff_offset):
    s_len = len(s)
    for each_s in str_list:
        if len(each_s) != s_len:
            return False
        diff = 0
        for i in range(0,s_len):
            if s[i] != each_s[i]:
                diff = diff + 1
            if diff > diff_offset:
                return False # if difference is more than required, then return false
    return True


print(isSame(["ccat","hpat","ppat"], "ppat", 2))
print(isSame(["ccat","hpat","ppatru"], "ppat", 2))
print(isSame(["ccat","hpat","that"], "ppat", 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Part of your solution is called "Levenshtein distance". You can read about more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

You can either implement it yourself or you can find python solution [here](https://stackabuse.com/levenshtein-distance-and-text-similarity-in-python/)

after implementing this, you can individually check the distance if it is within N with a loop

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to solve it.
there is a function named "distance" in the Levenshtein module:

```
from Levenshtein import distance
```

the function gets 2 string and return distance between them.
which is what are you looking for.

then I would implement it on all the items of the list (comprehension, loop etc..) and check if all true.