# How to pass in parameters to a SQL statement in Python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, function

I have a Python script that is calling a function that executes a SQL select statement but I keep getting errors that the Token ? was not valid.  How do I pass in variables so that they work with the SQL statement?  Here is my code:

```
def get_jde_udc_info(connection,product_code,userCode,librTable):

    c1=connection.cursor()
    
    length=c1.execute("select dtcdl, dtcnum from ?",(librTable) + " where dtsy=?",(product_code) + " and dtrt=?",(userCode))

    length=c1.fetchall() # <-- Using the .fetchone method from the Python cursor class that will return a single record or None if no more rows are available
    
    print(length)
```

Here is the function call in my script:

```
get_jde_udc_info(connection,"41","s1","testctl.f0004")
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use **%**

Like:

```
"SELECT field1, field2 FROM %s WHERE email = '%s'" % ('table', 'johndoe@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Hi @MatheusHernandes I entered my code like this:


length=c1.execute("select dtcdl, dtcnum from %s where dtsy=%s and dtrt=%s" % (librTable, product_code, userCode))

Now I get the error of Column or global variable S1 not found.  Any idea on this fix?

Comment: Check the types you are passing to that string, you can find a guide to % operator here http://www.python-ds.com/python-3-string-operators

Comment: That S1 is a value of the field in the AS400.  When I hardcode it it works fine.  What recommendation do you have for this?

Comment: I have no experience with AS400, but again, check the type of those variables
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-a-python-variables-type