# Python How to check if an item in a list is a float, and if so, change it to a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, floating-point, rtti

I am iterating through an excel sheet. Some of my info in some columns is coming across as a `float`. I have done everything I can through excel to try and make it not a float and it wont fix it.

I am using xlrd to read data.

```
for i in range(ws.nrows):
    row = ws.row_values(i)
    if type(row[1]) == 'float':
        row[1] = str(row[1])
    if ',' in row[1]:
        DO STUFF
```

I keep getting this error:

```
if ',' in row[1]:
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

For some reason this is not working. I can even print the type as I am iterating through the list, and it will say class 'float' but it never seems to go into the if type loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type` returns the actual `float` class, not the string `'float'`. The easiest way to check for the type would be to use the `isinstance` builtin function:

```
if isinstance(row[1], float):
    row[1] = str(row[1])
```

Comment: OMG thank you. This is exactly what I needed. The only problem I am having now is that a few of my numbers are a bit to big and I am getting this result: 8.156e+26 when I should be getting an 11 digit number.

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that the value of row[1] is a float (you didn't catch this properly in the first if statement - see below). When you evaluate `a in b`, Python tries to iterate through `b` to see whether `a` appears in it. This is why you're getting an error that floats are not iterable.

Now for the if statement - the `type` function doesn't return a string (though you can force it to by using i.e. `str(type(x))`. To check whether the type is a float, you want to do:

```
if type(row[1]) is float:
    # do stuff
    pass
else:
    # do other stuff
    pass
```

Most likely though, you'd be better off checking if it *isn't* a string -

```
if type(row[1]) is not str:
    # do stuff for floats
    pass
else:
    # do other stuff that involves checking if a substring is present
    pass
```

see also: [How to determine a Python variable's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-a-python-variables-type)