# How to check if a variable is float or int?

Tags: python, class, error-handling

When I construct a `__init__()` in a Car class, say, I want to check that variables `make` and `current_gas` to be string and float or integer (not negative), respectively.

Then how do I raise an appropriate error for each variable?

I tried

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self,make,current_gas):
        if type(make) != str:
            raise TypeError("Make should be a string")
        if not type(current_gas) == float or type(current_gas) == int:
            raise TypeError("gas amount should be float or int")
        if current_gas <=0:
            raise ValueError("gas amount should not be negative")
```

However, this `__init__()` is not working properly. How do I fix it?

Comment: What does "not working properly" mean? What is the exact behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine a Python variable's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-a-python-variables-type)

Comment: Note that in `not ... or ...` , the `not` only applies to the first boolean, not the whole branch

Comment: When I try to create a car obejct with positive current_gas, I see the error message.

Comment: Please **show the error message**. Also note that you have used `current_gas_level`, which does not seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: ```first_car=Car('Toyota','Corolla',20)``` gives ```gas amount should be float or int```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your boolean logic on the second if statement is wrong (`not` needs to be around both checks), however, you can use `isinstance` to simplify checking multiple types.

You also used `current_gas_level` instead of `current_gas`. Try something like this:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, current_gas):
        if not isinstance(make, str):
            raise TypeError("Make should be a string")
        if not isinstance(current_gas, (int, float)):
            raise TypeError("gas amount should be float or int")
        if current_gas <= 0:
            raise ValueError("gas amount should not be negative")

        self.make = make
        self.current_gas = current_gas
```

To make the definition a little easier to follow, I might also suggest using a dataclass and a `__post_init__` to do the validation.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union


@dataclass
class Car:
    make: str
    current_gas: Union[int, float]

    def __post_init__(self):
        if not isinstance(self.make, str):
            raise TypeError("Make should be a string")
        if not isinstance(self.current_gas, (int, float)):
            raise TypeError("gas amount should be float or int")
        if self.current_gas <= 0:
            raise ValueError("gas amount should not be negative")
```