# How do I check for type equality (is operator or x.GetType() == typeof(xType)) in IronPython?

Tags: c#, ironpython

> **Duplicate:** [What’s the canonical way to check for type in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

How do I check for type equality in IronPython?

I need the equivalent of the following C# code in IronPython:

```
if (x.GetType() == typeof(xType))
```

or

```
if (x is xType)
```

Comment: I voted to close: "exact duplicate".  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python.

Comment: Ehhh... not exactly a duplicate.  I really wasn't looking for the pythonic way to do it.  I was looking for the IronPythonic way of doing it - that is, using the .NET framework (or how to use the is keyword in IP.)

Comment: If you're looking for a pythonic way of doing it, don't do it! Type checking is very anti-pythonic. If you receive a type that doesn't work, the code will explode leaving the caller to pickup the pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from System import *
if x.GetType() == Type.GetType(xType):
```

Answer (score 0):

Say C is a static class, not fully qualified but imported into the iron python script
x is an instance of C
And A.B.C is the fully qualified name

Why don't these work?

```
x.GetType() == Type.GetType("A.B.C")
```

OR

```
x is Type.GetType("A.B.C")
```

OR

```
x is C
```

OR

```
x.GetType() == Type.GetType(C)
```

Comment: I ended up doing this:

x.GetType().Name == "C"