# How to find out if a Python object is a string?

Tags: python, string, types, compatibility

How can I check if a Python object is a string (either regular or Unicode)?

Comment: What Jason's referring to is duck typing (if it quacks like a duck it probably is a duck). In Python you often "let your code work" on any string-like object without testing whether it's a string or string subclass. For more info, see: http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-duck-typing

Comment: That's what I love about SO. I usually ask a question, it isn't answered, people tell me I shouldn't be doing that anyway and why, and I grow as a programmer. =)

Comment: +1: Just because an answer is rarely needed, doesn't mean the question is invalid.  Although, I think it's great to have a caution here, I don't think it merits demoting the question.

Comment: This is possibly the most legitimate use of type checking in Python. Strings are iterable, so distinguishing them from lists any other way is a bad idea.

Comment: There are definitely cases where it is necessary to distinguish strings from other iterables. For example, see the source code for PrettyPrinter in the pprint module.

Comment: I think duck typing is meant to work with polymorphism.  Some people  have a knee-jerk reaction against ALL python type checking.  [Ben's link](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-duck-typing) doesn't really speak against things where the types have fundamentally different behaviors.  My interpretation is that duck typing is meant to trust the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: Strings are not only iterables, they are *iterables of strings*. Distinguishing them from other iterables of string without 'cheating' is almost impossible. But then there's [stringlike](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stringlike) and the cheating code breaks.

Comment: Since lots of new people will probably read this: first be sure that you really do have to check. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45228730/2437514) might give some ideas on how to avoid the check.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string

Answer (score 330):

## Python 2

Use `isinstance(obj, basestring)` for an object-to-test `obj`.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#basestring).

Comment: All solutions on this page are all non-fool-proof. I mean `basestring` and `str` can both be overwritten which will make all this solutions invalid.

Answer (score 299):

## Python 3

In Python 3.x `basestring` is not available anymore, as `str` is the sole string type (with the semantics of Python 2.x's `unicode`).

So the check in Python 3.x is just:

```
isinstance(obj_to_test, str)
```

This follows [the fix](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-basestring) of the official `2to3` conversion tool: converting `basestring` to `str`.

Comment: This does not work for string like objects : isinstance(collections.UserString("foe"), str) == False

Comment: @loutre Thanks for your comment. I did not come across the User collections (`UserString`, `UserDict`, `UserList`) before. Those types already predate Python 2. As those types do not inherit from the build-in types `str`, `dict` or `list` the isinstance call will not work. FYI: Because of this it is not guaranteed that those types can be used as a drop-in replacement. E.g. the regex module `re` does not work with `UserString` (at least with Python 3.8.2).

Answer (score 199):

## Python 2

To check if an object `o` is a string type of a subclass of a string type:

```
isinstance(o, basestring)
```

because both `str` and `unicode` are subclasses of `basestring`.

To check if the type of `o` is exactly `str`:

```
type(o) is str
```

To check if `o` is an instance of `str` or any subclass of `str`:

```
isinstance(o, str)
```

The above also work for Unicode strings if you replace `str` with `unicode`.

However, you may not need to do explicit type checking at all.  "Duck typing" may fit your needs.  See http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-duck-typing.

See also [What’s the canonical way to check for type in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Comment: local variable 'str' referenced before assignment

Comment: @johnktejik python3 vs python2. You need to check for `basestring` in py2.

Answer (score 99):

## Python 2 and 3

#### (cross-compatible)

If you want to check with no regard for Python version (2.x vs 3.x), use [**`six`**](http://pythonhosted.org/six/) ([PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/)) and its `string_types` attribute:

```
import six

if isinstance(obj, six.string_types):
    print('obj is a string!')
```

Within `six` (a very light-weight single-file module), it's simply doing [this](https://github.com/benjaminp/six/blob/68112f3193c7d4bef5ad86ed1b6ed528edd9093d/six.py#L40):

```
import sys
PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3

if PY3:
    string_types = str
else:
    string_types = basestring
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`future`](http://python-future.org/) ([PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/future/)) to even keep the name: `from past.builtins import basestring`

Comment: BTW the [Cheat Sheet](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#basestring) is a great resource for Python version compatibility.

Comment: What about not using any imports? First try `basestring` and then fall back to `str`. E.g.
`def is_string(obj):
    try:
        return isinstance(obj, basestring)  # python 2
    except NameError:
        return isinstance(obj, str)  # python 3
`

Answer (score 23):

I found this ans more `pythonic`:

```
if type(aObject) is str:
    #do your stuff here
    pass
```

since type objects are singleton, **is** can be used to do the compare the object to the str type

Comment: This is not the general recommended way of testing for type, because of inheritance: `isinstance(obj_to_test, str)` is obviously meant to test for type, and it has the advantage of using the same procedure as for other, non-str cases.

Answer (score 17):

If one wants to stay away from explicit type-checking (and there *are* good reasons to stay away from it), probably the safest part of the string protocol to check is:

```
str(maybe_string) == maybe_string
```

It won't iterate through an iterable or iterator, it won't call a list-of-strings a string and it correctly detects a [stringlike](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stringlike) as a string.

Of course there are drawbacks. For example, `str(maybe_string)` may be a heavy calculation. As so often, the answer is *it depends*.

EDIT: As [@Tcll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2131849/tcll) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303243/how-to-find-out-if-a-python-object-is-a-string/38636757?noredirect=1#comment104628091_38636757) in the comments, the question actually asks for a way to detect both unicode strings and bytestrings. On Python 2 this answer will fail with an exception for unicode strings that contain non-ASCII characters, and on Python 3 it will return `False` for all bytestrings.

Comment: In the case of objects that initialize with representation data, this may not work as expected... `b = b'test'; r = str(b) == b` where `b` holds the same data as `str(b)` but (being a bytes object) does not validate as a string.

Comment: @Tcll Right, the question actually says "either regular or Unicode". I guess I didn't read it properly.

Answer (score 13):

In order to check if your variable is something you could go like:

```
s='Hello World'
if isinstance(s,str):
#do something here,
```

The output of isistance will give you a boolean True or False value so you can adjust accordingly.
You can check the expected acronym of your value by initially using:
    type(s)
This will return you type 'str' so you can use it in the isistance function.

Answer (score 13):

Its simple, use the following code (we assume the object mentioned to be obj)-

```
if type(obj) == str:
    print('It is a string')
else:
    print('It is not a string.')
```

Answer (score 5):

I might deal with this in the duck-typing style, like others mention.  How do I know a string is really a string? well, obviously by *converting* it to a string!

```
def myfunc(word):
    word = unicode(word)
    ...
```

If the arg is already a string or unicode type, real_word will hold its value unmodified.  If the object passed implements a `__unicode__` method, that is used to get its unicode representation.  If the object passed cannot be used as a string, the `unicode` builtin raises an exception.

Answer (score 4):

```
isinstance(your_object, basestring)
```

will be True if your object is indeed a string-type. 'str' is reserved word.

my apologies,
the correct answer is using 'basestring' instead of 'str' in order of it to include unicode strings as well - as been noted above by one of the other responders.

Comment: Doesn't work for unicode objects, which were explicitly requested in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This evening I ran into a situation in which I **thought** I was going to have to check against the `str` type, but it turned out I did not.

My approach to solving the problem will probably work in many situations, so I offer it below in case others reading this question are interested (Python 3 only).

```
# NOTE: fields is an object that COULD be any number of things, including:
# - a single string-like object
# - a string-like object that needs to be converted to a sequence of 
# string-like objects at some separator, sep
# - a sequence of string-like objects
def getfields(*fields, sep=' ', validator=lambda f: True):
    '''Take a field sequence definition and yield from a validated
     field sequence. Accepts a string, a string with separators, 
     or a sequence of strings'''
    if fields:
        try:
            # single unpack in the case of a single argument
            fieldseq, = fields
            try:
                # convert to string sequence if string
                fieldseq = fieldseq.split(sep)
            except AttributeError:
                # not a string; assume other iterable
                pass
        except ValueError:
            # not a single argument and not a string
            fieldseq = fields
        invalid_fields = [field for field in fieldseq if not validator(field)]
        if invalid_fields:
            raise ValueError('One or more field names is invalid:\n'
                             '{!r}'.format(invalid_fields))
    else:
        raise ValueError('No fields were provided')
    try:
        yield from fieldseq
    except TypeError as e:
        raise ValueError('Single field argument must be a string'
                         'or an interable') from e
```

Some tests:

```
from . import getfields

def test_getfields_novalidation():
    result = ['a', 'b']
    assert list(getfields('a b')) == result
    assert list(getfields('a,b', sep=',')) == result
    assert list(getfields('a', 'b')) == result
    assert list(getfields(['a', 'b'])) == result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test it by concatenating with an empty string:

```
def is_string(s):
  try:
    s += ''
  except:
    return False
  return True
```

**Edit**:

Correcting my answer after comments pointing out that this fails with lists

```
def is_string(s):
  return isinstance(s, basestring)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's safe to assume that if the final character of the output of `repr()` is a `'` or `"`, then whatever it is, it aught to be considered some kind of string.

```
def isStr(o):
    return repr(o)[-1] in '\'"'
```

I'm assuming that `repr` won't be doing anything too heavy and that it'll return a string of at least one character. You can support empty strings by using something like

```
repr(o)[-1:].replace('"', "'") == "'"
```

but that's still assuming `repr` returns a string at all.

Answer (score -4):

```
if type(varA) == str or type(varB) == str:
    print 'string involved'
```

from 
EDX - online course
MITx: 6.00.1x Introduction to Computer Science and Programming Using Python

Comment: This is probably the worst possible way to check.  Not only does it exclude unicode objects, it even excludes subclasses of `str`!

Answer (score -4):

For a nice duck-typing approach for string-likes that has the bonus of working with both Python 2.x and 3.x:

```
def is_string(obj):
    try:
        obj + ''
        return True
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

[wisefish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920374/wisefish) was close with the duck-typing before he switched to the `isinstance` approach, except that `+=` has a different meaning for lists than `+` does.

Comment: Well, you have two downvotes and no one provided a comment. I've not downvoted but I don't like your solution because:

* Too verbose. You shouldn't need to define a function to do this.
* Expensive. Catching exceptions is not good for performance.
* Error prone. Other object might implement __add__, see a string, and raise another type of exception, which is not TypeError.

Comment: Also here you are employing the duck-typing approach, which is beautiful, but end up with throwing and catching exception just to find out something, which is not beautiful.

Comment: This may be legitimately the only surefire way to distinguish between a string-like and some other iterable of string. One could look for attributes like `isalpha`, but who knows what methods would be safe to look for?

Comment: I [realized](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38636757/260122) that the `__str__` method plus equality may actually be the fool-proof one. But even that is not without caveats.

Comment: @santiagobasulto exceptions are cheap in Python. If you expect the error 1% of the time, `try` can be faster. If you expect it 99% of the time, maybe not. The performance difference being minimal, it's better to be idiomatic unless you profile your code and identify it as actually being slow.