# How to elegantly get top level text of a html td with BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Below is a simple html segment to parse with beautifulsoup4 and I hope to extract the top level raw text *hello*.

```
mysoup = BeautifulSoup('<td>hello<script type="text/javascript">world</script></td>')
```

And I've tried several intuitive ways but without expected results:

```
mysoup.text            # u'helloworld'
mysoup.contents        # [<html><body><td>hello<script type="text/javascript">world</script></td></body></html>]
list(mysoup.strings)   # [u'hello ', u'world']
```

So how to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get a reference to the `td` node. Then, iterate through its children and see which of them [are strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1303252/390819):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
mysoup = BeautifulSoup('<td>hello<script type="text/javascript">world</script></td>')
td = mysoup.find('td')
print [s for s in td.children if isinstance(s, basestring)]
```