# Drop Pandas DataFrame rows that contain string of interger

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas DataFrame with columns

```
[Brand, CPL1, CPL4, Part Number, Calendar Year/Month, value, type]
```

When they come out of StatsModels X13, they occasionaly have very large string representations of integers in values that make no sense in their context, EG:

```
[float(1.2), float(1.3), str("63478"), float(1.1)]
```

How can I remove the rows where this has happened? Due to them being string representations of integers, I cannot cast them or any similar method.

Comment: What's the source of the data?  What's the origin of the defective columns (or rows in columns)?  Some specific sample data and/or code would help.

Comment: The origin is an SAP Hana xls file being imported to DataFrame, flattening each part number to a series and coming out of statsmodels x13. The series that come out of x13 contain those irregularities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with checking if `type` is [`string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303243/how-to-find-out-if-a-python-object-is-a-string):

**DataFrame**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[float(1.2), float(1.3), str("63478"), float(1.1)],
                  [float(1.2), float(1.3), float(1.1), str("63478")]]).T

print (df)
      0      1
0    1.2    1.2
1    1.3    1.3
2  63478    1.1
3    1.1  63478

print (df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)))
       0      1
0  False  False
1  False  False
2   True  False
3  False   True

print (df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)).any(axis=1))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool

print (df[~df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)).any(axis=1)])
     0    1
0  1.2  1.2
1  1.3  1.3
```

**Series**:

```
s = pd.Series([float(1.2), float(1.3), str("63478"), float(1.1)])
print (s)
0      1.2
1      1.3
2    63478
3      1.1
dtype: object

print (s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

print (s[~s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))])
0    1.2
1    1.3
3    1.1
dtype: object
```