# How to check if an integer or string exists in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to know how I can check if an integer is in a list. Here is some code I made:

```
# "1" is a string. 10 is an integer.
my_list = ["1", 10]
if int in my_list:
    print("Integer in the list!")
```

What is wrong with this code? And how do I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Cargcigenicate, both `int == "1"` and `int == 10` are `False`, so the overall check is `False`. What you want to do is check whether or not an element in the list is an *instance* of `int`, not whether or not they are *equal* to `int`.

This can be accomplished a bit more concisely by using the builtin [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) along with a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
if any(isinstance(x, int) for x in my_list):
    ...
```

Note that in general [using `isinstance` should be prefered over `type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance) when reasoning about the type of an object since the former takes inheritance into account.

Comment: Good calls. A little more complicated, but definately the better option

Comment: I also have one more question, how do I check if an item is not a str?

Comment: @MacintoshFan The same technique applies, just [check whether the elements are not strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26535728/11082165). I assume you're familiar with the `not` operator?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is, `int == 10` is false. `int` is a class, and `10` is an instance of the class. That doesn't mean however that they equate to each other.

You'd need to do some preprocessing first. There's many ways to do this, and it ultimately depends on what your end goal is, but as an example:

```
my_list = ["1", 10]

# Create a new list that holds the type of each element in my_list
types = [type(x) for x in my_list]

if int in types:  # And check against the types, not the instances themselves
    print("Integer in the list!")
```

Comment: Assuming that is the most simple way?

Comment: @MacintoshFan If you really wanted to use `in`, probably. The later ate way would be to use a `for x in my_list:` loop and do something like `if type(x) == int:` inside the loop