# String Check with if Statement in Python

Tags: python, string, if-statement, input, controls

I want to check input is an equal to string or not. But, my code cannot see if statement. I think the problem is in if statement equation:

```
    name = input("Name: ")
    if name != str:
        print("Please enter letter answer ...")
        name = str(input("Name: "))
    else:
        print(input(name))
```

I guess I cannot write name != str. But I don't know how to check input is equal to string. ???

Comment: Your input cannot be anything but a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out if a Python object is a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303243/how-to-find-out-if-a-python-object-is-a-string)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When asking your question, try to format your code properly, using correct indentation, especially in Python where indents matter

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't check an input string against a type `str`. inputs will always be of type `str`. If you want to check for strings in general, you can use `type(var) == str`.

Answer (score 0):

`input` will always return a string, so you don't have to check if it is a string.

Also, this line: `print(input(name))`  asks for input again, you probably just want `print(name)`

This code should work just fine for what you would want:

```py
name = input("Name: ")
print(name)
```

If you want the name to not include any numbers or spaces, so it is just a single name, you can try `isalpha()`:

```py
if name.isalpha():
    pass # Do your stuff with the name here
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend  using isinstance(object, type) function because it is a boolean function already
for example: `if isinstance(name,str):`

you can also use the type() function if you want to use an approach more like what you are already using. The type() function can be useful overall
for example:

```
if type(name) != str:
   print("Error; name is ",type(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, Whatever you enter as input, the input() function converts it into a string. If you enter an integer value, still it will convert it into a string.

Using `isaplha()` like @funie200 said:

```
while True:
    name = input("Name: ")

    if name.isalpha():
        print(name.title)
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter your name...")
```