# Check if the input is a string in python

Tags: python, function, loops, try-catch

I am trying to check if my input is a string with try-except block. The function runs without an error. However it checks if the input is an integer, not string. How can I inverse this?

```
def lexicon(word):
    while True:
        try:
            a=str(input(word))
            print("Input is a string. string = ", a)
        except ValueError:
            print("Oops..Input is not supposed to be a number. Try again!")
    return a
b=lexicon("Enter the word you'd like: ")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out if a Python object is a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303243/how-to-find-out-if-a-python-object-is-a-string)

Comment: The `input` function always returns a string, so checking if it is a string is pretty pointless. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I can't even understand why he has passed the object parameter into input? And @Antimon pointed out correctly that he has converted every word to string so it's pointless to use try-except block for numbers as they are going to be converted to string anyways.. Problem statement is not clear

Comment: @Raghav not only that, but `str(input(...))` is redundant since the return value of `input` is always a string anyway. This code would make sense if it was `int(input(...))`, but OP would need to clarify here.

Comment: @Antimon If the input is an integer I want to tell the user that its an error and they need to enter a string as the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed with user pavel in the comments to his answer, there are two different styles to code for a problem like this: EAFP ("Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission"), meaning that you make your code work on an assumption and take action if it fails; and LBYL ("Look Before You Leap"), in which you first check whether your assumption is true, and *then* choose the appropriate action to take.

The `try/except` route is EAFP, since it just executes the code in the `try` block without bothering to first check whether it would work. If you want to do it in LYBL style, you would explicitly need to ascertain whether the user input is a string representation of a numeric value, and then act accordingly. I'll provide skeletal code for both approaches below. However, note that Python is a little weird compared to other languages in that it seems to have a certain cultural favour for EAFP.

Also, since you are only asking about checking for integers, I will focus on that here. This means that the code will accept floats as valid inputs.

### EAFP: `try/except`

The problem that presumably trips you up is that `input` *always* returns a string, so testing if it is a string is nonsensical and will always yield `True`. However, note that `try/except` is only an abrigded version of error handling that you can do in Python; the full version is `try/except/else/finally`. The `else` block takes effect if *no* `except` blocks are executed, and `finally` is *always* run at the end. So you could check whether your input is an integer, and make the program raise a failure if that check *succeeds*. I admit however that this does seem a bit backwards.

```
try:
    a = int(input())
except ValueError:
    # do whatever
else:
    raise ValueError("Input must not be an integer")
```

### LBYL: `if/else`

`str` objects have several methods to test their contents without having to run into errors. For example, `.isalpha()` checks if all characters are in the alphabet (which returns `False` however if you include spaces and special characters); `isnumeric()` checks whether the string is a representation of a number; etc. See a full list [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp). So depending on what kind of inputs you want to allow, you would need to use one of these methods, or a combination of them, in an `if` block. The code below essentially does the same thing as the `try/except/else` version above, using `.isdigit()` which returns `True` if all characters in the string are digits (i.e., the same kind of input for which `int(a)` would succeed).

Note also that I am making use of the new assignment operator `:=` in this code, which is new to Python 3.8. This way, you don't need to explicitly assign the variable `a` first, however it's a bit harder to catch where the code actually executes an `input()` function. If you code for backwards compatibility, or don't like the look of this, you'd have to go with the classical `a = input()` first.

```
if (a := input()).isdigit():
    raise ValueError("Input must not be an integer")

# do whatever
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed, clear explanation!

Answer (score 2):

If you want specifically to *check* the value type of the string, you're better off using `if/else` and `isinstance`:

```
if not isinstance(word, str):
    raise TypeError(f"Expecting a string as a value, not {type(word)}.")
else:
    #do something
```

Comment: Note however that Python favours the [EAFP style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python#11360880)  ("Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission"), so `try/except` would probably be considered more idiomatic.

Comment: @Antimon, I guess, that really depends on what your code is doing. If the variable is being used immediately or very close to where it's declared, `try-except` sounds like a good idea, but if the variable is declared early and is only used much later in execution, I think it's better to do an early check and raise an error.

Comment: Also I think that `if isinstance()` and `if not isinstance()` are both very idiomatic in Python but I may be wrong.

Comment: How would you do this with try/except block?

Comment: agree with pavel, better to avoid try/except where it is not needed as it is bad for performance. Testing with isinstance() is very pythonic