# How to skip the lines of an excel file loaded to a Pandas dataframe if data types are wrong (checking types)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have just coded this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

files = os.listdir(path)

#AllData = pd.DataFrame() 

for f in files:
    info = pd.read_excel(f, "File")
    info.fillna(0)
    try:
        info['Country'] = info['Country'].astype('str')
    except ValueError:
        continue
    try:
        info['Name'] = info['Name'].astype('str')
    except ValueError:
        continue
    try:
        info['Age'] = info['Age'].astype('int')
    except ValueError as error:
        continue
        
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Output.xlsx")
    info.to_excel(writer, "Sheet 1")
    writer.save()
```

It reads some excel files, selects a sheet named "File" and put all its data in a dataframe.
Once it is done, it returns all the records.

What I want is to check the types of all the values of each column, and to skip the line in the reading source if the type is not the one I want for this column.
Finally I want to record in the output the data that fits the types I want.

I tried to use `astype` but that's not working as expected.

Thus, read source - check astype - if not astype - skip line and keep running the code.

Comment: This code is invalid. It's not possible to assign a loop to a variable like that.

Answer (score 1):

I first have to say that *type checking* and *type casting* are 2 different things.

Pandas' `astype` is used for *type casting* (it will "convert" a type to another type, it will not check if a value is of certain type) .

But if what you want is to not keep the rows that can't be cast as numeric type, you can do it like this:

```
info['Age'] = pd.to_numeric(info['Age'], errors='coerce')
info = info.dropna()
```

Note that you don't have to use a try-except block here.
Here, we use `to_numeric` because we can pass `errors='coerce'`, so that if it can't be cast, the value will be `NaN`, and then we use `dropna()` in order to remove rows contaiing `NaN`s.

### Update about type checking:

Here I'll add some informations you asked in comment about how to check types in pandas dataframes:

- How to get the types inferred by pandas for each column?
- How to check the types of all values of the whole dataframe?
- Some useful functions for type checkings
- Ways to check types in Python

**How to get the types infered by pandas for each column?**

`columns_dtypes = df.dtypes`

It will output something like this:

```
Country     object
Name        object
Age        int64
dtype: object
```

Note that i your column "Age" contains some `Nan` values the `dtype` could be `float64`.

And when a column contains strings, the `dtype` will be `object` when you'll load your excel file to a dataframe like in your example.
See below for how to check if an object is a Python string (type `str`).

Pandas documentation listing all dtypes: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html?highlight=basics#dtypes

Other useful information about Pandas dtypes : [what are all the dtypes that pandas recognizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245848/what-are-all-the-dtypes-that-pandas-recognizes)

**How to check the types of all values of the whole dataframe?**

There are numerous ways of doing this.

Here is one way. I choose this code because it's clear and simple:

```
# Iterate over all the columns
for (column_name, column_data) in info.iteritems():
    print("column_name: ", column_name)
    print("column_data: ", column_data.values)

    # Iterate over all the values of this column
    for column_value in column_data.values:
        # print the value and its type
        print(column_value, type(column_value))
        # So here you can check the type and do something with that
        # For example, log the error to a log file
```

**Some useful functions for type checkings:**

How to test if `object` (as returned by `df.dtypes` like in the output above) is a string?
`isinstance(object_to_test, str)`
See: [How to find out if a Python object is a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303243/how-to-find-out-if-a-python-object-is-a-string)

Now, if you have a column that contains strings (like "hello", "world", etc.) and some of these strings are `int`, and you want to check if these stings represent a number, or a `int` you can use these functions:

How to check if a string is an `int`?

```
def str_is_int(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

How to check if a string is an number?

```
def str_is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Python's strings have a method `isdigit()`, but it can't be used to check for int or number, because it will fail with `one = "+1"` or `minus_one = "-1"`.

**And finally, here are 2 common ways to check "types" in Python:**

```
object_to_test = 1

print( type(object_to_test) is int)
print( type(object_to_test) in (int, float) ) # Check is is one of those types

print( isinstance(object_to_test, int) )
```

`isinstance(object_to_test, str)` will return `True` if `object_to_test` is of type `str` OR any sublass of `str`.

`type(object_to_test) is str` will return `True` if  `object_to_test` is ONLY of type `str` (excluding any subclass of `str`)

There is also a libray called `pandas-stubs` that could be useful  for type safety: https://github.com/VirtusLab/pandas-stubs.

Comment: I need also to check a type to record a logfile to know where is the error in the spreadsheet.