# Check if a number is int or float

Tags: python

Here's how I did it:

```
inNumber = somenumber
inNumberint = int(inNumber)
if inNumber == inNumberint:
    print "this number is an int"
else:
    print "this number is a float"
```

Something like that.
Are there any nicer looking ways to do this?

Comment: The trick is to search on SO for all the other times this question was asked.  Each of those will provide a repeat of the same, standard answer.

Comment: related: [How to check if a float value is a whole number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21583758/4279).

Comment: @Wooble: it fails for [larger numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26447472/4279).

Comment: `assert isinstance(inNumber, (int, float)), "inNumber is neither int nor float, it is %s" % type(inNumber)` was what I was looking for when I found this question with Google.

Comment: The questions is not particularly well put.  Is the OP asking: 1) "What is the intrinsic Python variable type of the variable `somenumber`?"  2) Is `somenumber` a whole number?  3) Is `somenumber` a string that is known to represent a number, but is does it represent an integer or floating point value?  Some COUNTER CASES would help respondents suggest a suitable solution.

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64132078/8321339

Answer (score 403):

Use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance).

```
>>> x = 12
>>> isinstance(x, int)
True
>>> y = 12.0
>>> isinstance(y, float)
True
```

So:

```
>>> if isinstance(x, int):
        print('x is a int!')

x is a int!
```

In case of long integers, the above won't work. So you need to do:

```
>>> x = 12L
>>> import numbers
>>> isinstance(x, numbers.Integral)
True
>>> isinstance(x, int)
False
```

Comment: wouldn't `issubclass` be more generic?

Comment: @David: `issubclass` would be an error, as it works on classes. `isinstance` checks if a given object is an instance of a class *or one of that class's subclasses*, so it's perfectly generic. Methinks that `isinstance(obj, cls)` is equivalent to `issubclass(obj.__class__, cls)`

Comment: This doesn't work for other integer types, for example if `x = 12L`. I know only `int` was asked for, but it's nice to fix other problems before they happen. The most generic is probably `isinstance(x, numbers.Integral)`.

Comment: @delnan Thanks, I wasn't aware that isinstance checked for subclasses. Thinking about it, it seems obvious now that it makes no sense to do anything else. If one wants to check to class identity then one can write `type(obj) is cls`.

Comment: @Scott: I have no idea about `numbers`, feel free to update the question so that it can help someone in case they end up here searching for it.

Comment: @Scott are all built-in integral types in Python subclasses of `numbers.Integral`?

Comment: @David: `assert isinstance(1, numbers.Integral) and isinstance(1L, numbers.Integral)` (and in Python 3, that's moot because `long` is removed and `int` is always arbitrary-precision).

Comment: @David Heffernan: `numbers.Integral` is an Abstract Base Class that allows anyone to write classes that promise to behave as integers. Any built-in type certainly works, but results might be mixed otherwise, for example `numpy.int16` isn't (yet) `Integral`.

Comment: For Python 2, there is also the direct double check: `isinstance(x, (int, long))`.

Comment: WARNING: bools are instances of integers also. See `isinstance(True, int)`

Comment: Are there still cases for Python3 where `isinstance(somebignumber, int)` returns `False`? Is the only advantage now that other integer-like types are checked with `numbers.Integral`?

Comment: Is the last section incorrect? `isinstance(12, float)` returns `False` for me.

Comment: This will fail if the type is np.float32 or similar. Check this answer for a broader float or numeric check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78167784/2738240

Answer (score 158):

I like @ninjagecko's answer the most.

This would also work:

> for Python 2.x

```
isinstance(n, (int, long, float))
```

> Python 3.x doesn't have ***long***

```
isinstance(n, (int, float))
```

there is also type ***complex*** for complex numbers

Comment: A sidenote, because booleans will resolve to True (e.g. `isinstance(False, (int, float)) = True`), I needed `not isinstance(n, bool) and isinstance(n, (int, float))` instead

Comment: Lifesaver.. I did not notice `isinstance()` could check for multiple types..

Answer (score 66):

(note: this will return `True` for type `bool`, at least in cpython, which may not be what you want. Thank you commenters.)

One-liner:

```
isinstance(yourNumber, numbers.Real)
```

This avoids some problems:

```
>>> isinstance(99**10,int)
False
```

Demo:

```
>>> import numbers

>>> someInt = 10
>>> someLongInt = 100000L
>>> someFloat = 0.5

>>> isinstance(someInt, numbers.Real)
True
>>> isinstance(someLongInt, numbers.Real)
True
>>> isinstance(someFloat, numbers.Real)
True
```

Comment: In Python 3 `isinstance(99**10,int)` is `True`.

Comment: This also passes `Bool`. `instance(True, numbers.Real)` is `True`

Comment: @carkod. Because bool is a subclass of int

Answer (score 15):

You can use modulo to determine if x is an integer numerically. The `isinstance(x, int)` method only determines if x is an integer by type:

```
def isInt(x):
    if x%1 == 0:
        print "X is an integer"
    else:
        print "X is not an integer"
```

Comment: @dylnmc Then you can use the isinstance() method to determine if x is a number. Also, 3.2 % 1 yields 0.2. If a number is evenly divisible by 1, it is an integer numerically. This method was useful to me even though it may not have been for you.

Comment: this is true; `x%1 == 0` should be true for only ints (but it will also be true for floats with only a zero following decimal point). If you know it's going to be an int (eg, if this is a param to a function), then you could just check with modulo. I bet that is faster than `Math.floor(x) == x`. On the not-so-bright side, this will be `True` if you pass a float like `1.0` or `5.0`, and you will encounter the same problem using what the original poster mentioned in his/her question.

Answer (score 11):

It's easier to ask forgiveness than ask permission.  Simply perform the operation.  If it works, the object was of an acceptable, suitable, proper type.  If the operation doesn't work, the object was not of a suitable type.  Knowing the type rarely helps.

Simply attempt the operation and see if it works.

```
inNumber = somenumber
try:
    inNumberint = int(inNumber)
    print "this number is an int"
except ValueError:
    pass
try:
    inNumberfloat = float(inNumber)
    print "this number is a float"
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: Is there any reason to do this when `type` and `isinstance` can do the job?

Comment: int(1.5) doesn't raise ValueError, and you obviously know that--giving a wrong answer on purpose?  Seriously?

Comment: @Glenn: I assume S.Lott understood the question as "check if a **string** is an int or float" (in which case it would actually be a good solution).

Comment: @A A: `class MetaInt(type): pass; class Int(int): __metaclass__ = MetaInt; type(Int(1)) == int`. (Sorry for the bad syntax but I cannot do more on one line.)

Comment: @A A: Yes.  The reason is that this is simpler and more reliable.  The distinction between `int` and `float` may not even be relevant for many algorithms.  Requesting the type explicitly is usually a sign of bad polymorphism or an even more serious design problem.  In short.  Don't Check for Types.  It's Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Ask Permission.

Comment: `import math; print math.isnan('hi')` fails for me because `isnan` expects an `int` or a `float`. I want to wrap it so that `_isnan('hi')` does return `False` for me. I want `_isnan(float('nan'))` to return `True` but `_isnan('nan')` to return `False`. The reason why is somewhat complicated - it has to do with sending JSON-like input to a custom web service we want a distinction between `?x="nan"` and `?x=nan` (when supplied in the URL). Now, I believe that your approach would treat `'nan'` and `float('nan')` the same way. That is not what I want. Is the problem with duck types or math.isnan?

Comment: This is the Pythonic way.

Comment: I would inverse the 2 blocs to start with `float` then `int`. Otherwise `'3'` will be seen as a float whereas it is actually an int.

Comment: @user225312 if the value is derived from a numpy array or pandas series/dataframe, such as `x = pd.Series([0.2], dtype=np.float32)[0]`, it can have floating data types that cannot be detected with a simple `isinstance(x, float)` or `type(x) is float`. And since there seem to be countless other float-like data types, it seems to be impossible to detect them with isinstance or type. But the solution proposed in this answer isn't really what I've been looking for either, since it also detects `1.5` as an int and `"1.5"` (string) as a float

Answer (score 10):

What you can do too is using`type()`
Example:

```
if type(inNumber) == int : print "This number is an int"
elif type(inNumber) == float : print "This number is a float"
```

Comment: This would fail in the [admittedly rare] case that the number in question is a SUBCLASS of int or float.  (Hence why "isinstance" would be considered "better", IMO.)

Answer (score 9):

Tried in Python version 3.6.3 Shell

```
>>> x = 12
>>> import numbers
>>> isinstance(x, numbers.Integral)
True
>>> isinstance(x,int)
True
```

Couldn't figure out anything to work for.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a piece of code that checks whether a number is an integer or not, it works for both Python 2 and Python 3.

```
import sys

if sys.version < '3':
    integer_types = (int, long,)
else:
    integer_types = (int,)

isinstance(yourNumber, integer_types)  # returns True if it's an integer
isinstance(yourNumber, float)  # returns True if it's a float
```

Notice that Python 2 has both types `int` and `long`, while Python 3 has only type `int`. [Source](http://python3porting.com/differences.html#long).

If you want to check whether your number is a `float` that represents an `int`, do this

```
(isinstance(yourNumber, float) and (yourNumber).is_integer())  # True for 3.0
```

If you don't need to distinguish between int and float, and are ok with either, then ninjagecko's answer is the way to go

```
import numbers

isinstance(yourNumber, numbers.Real)
```

Answer (score 7):

how about this solution?

```
if type(x) in (float, int):
    # do whatever
else:
    # do whatever
```

Answer (score 7):

I know it's an old thread but this is something that I'm using and I thought it might help.

It works in python 2.7 and python 3< .

```
def is_float(num):
    """
    Checks whether a number is float or integer

    Args:
        num(float or int): The number to check

    Returns:
        True if the number is float
    """
    return not (float(num)).is_integer()


class TestIsFloat(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_float(self):
        self.assertTrue(is_float(2.2))

    def test_int(self):
        self.assertFalse(is_float(2))
```

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure why this hasn't been proposed before, but how about using the built-in Python method on a float called [`is_integer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer)? Basically you could give it some number cast as a float, and ask whether it is an integer or not. For instance:

```py
>>> (-13.0).is_integer()
True

>>> (3.14).is_integer()
False
```

For completeness, however, consider:

```py
isinstance(i, int) or i.is_integer()
```

Comment: It's a very good proposition. It's a build-in fonction so it's good !
It can be apply to a series with a lambda.
```python
_df["col_to_test].apply(lambda x : x.is_integer())
```

Answer (score 5):

pls check this: import numbers

```
import math

a = 1.1 - 0.1
print a 

print isinstance(a, numbers.Integral)
print math.floor( a )
if (math.floor( a ) == a):
    print "It is an integer number"
else:
    print False
```

Although X is float but the value is integer, so if you want to check the value is integer you cannot use isinstance and you need to compare values not types.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with simple if statement

#### To check for float

if type(a)==type(1.1)

#### To check for integer type

if type(a)==type(1)

Comment: Why evaluate the right side when you can use `int` or `float`? Don't use this for this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
absolute = abs(x)
rounded = round(absolute)
if absolute - rounded == 0:
  print 'Integer number'
else:
  print 'notInteger number'
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: Try this

```
inNumber = [32, 12.5, 'e', 82, 52, 92, '1224.5', '12,53',
            10000.000, '10,000459', 
           'This is a sentance, with comma number 1 and dot.', '121.124']

try:

    def find_float(num):
        num = num.split('.')
        if num[-1] is not None and num[-1].isdigit():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    for i in inNumber:
        i = str(i).replace(',', '.')
        if '.' in i and find_float(i):
            print('This is float', i)
        elif i.isnumeric():
            print('This is an integer', i)
        else:
            print('This is not a number ?', i)

except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

Comment: Yes I did and it didn't work. And I'm pretty sure you didn't really try it. Because it doesn't work.

Comment: Certainly, there is a less offensive way to respond. Although you are right I just run more test's it doesn't work in every case.

Comment: @JJJ How about this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use the most basic of type inference that python has:

```
>>> # Float Check
>>> myNumber = 2.56
>>> print(type(myNumber) == int)
False
>>> print(type(myNumber) == float)
True
>>> print(type(myNumber) == bool)
False
>>>
>>> # Integer Check
>>> myNumber = 2
>>> print(type(myNumber) == int)
True
>>> print(type(myNumber) == float)
False
>>> print(type(myNumber) == bool)
False
>>>
>>> # Boolean Check
>>> myNumber = False
>>> print(type(myNumber) == int)
False
>>> print(type(myNumber) == float)
False
>>> print(type(myNumber) == bool)
True
>>>
```

Easiest and Most Resilient Approach in my Opinion

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_int(x):
  absolute = abs(x)
  rounded = round(absolute)
  if absolute - rounded == 0:
    print str(x) + " is an integer"
  else:
    print str(x) +" is not an integer"


is_int(7.0) # will print 7.0 is an integer
```

Comment: func checks for ints but also returns true for floats that are .0

Comment: Please explain why/how your contribution solves the OPs question.

Comment: @Heri he is looking to check if a number is an int or a float, the function I defined can do that, abs is an inbuilt python func that returns the absolute value of the number, round is also an inbuilt func that rounds off the number, if I subtract the rounded number from the absolute one, and I get a zero, then the number is an int, or it has a zero as after its decimal places

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
def is_int(x):
  absolute = abs(x)
  rounded = round(absolute)
  return absolute - rounded == 0
```

Answer (score -5):

`variable.isnumeric` checks if a value is an integer:

```
 if myVariable.isnumeric:
    print('this varibale is numeric')
 else:
    print('not numeric')
```