# How to check if a float value is a whole number

Tags: python, floating-point

I am trying to find the largest cube root that is a whole number, that is less than 12,000.

```
processing = True
n = 12000
while processing:
    n -= 1
    if n ** (1/3) == #checks to see if this has decimals or not
```

I am not sure how to check if it is a whole number or not though! I could convert it to a string then use indexing to check the end values and see whether they are zero or not, that seems rather cumbersome though. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: it would make it easier to work from the cube root n --> (n * n * n < 12000)

Comment: Btw do you mean largest integer cube? That can be computed for small values by rounding down with `int(12000**(1/3))**3`

Answer (score 573, accepted):

To check if a float value is a whole number, use the [`float.is_integer()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer):

```
>>> (1.0).is_integer()
True
>>> (1.555).is_integer()
False
```

The method was added to the `float` type in Python 2.6.

Take into account that in Python 2, `1/3` is `0` (floor division for integer operands!), and that floating point arithmetic can be imprecise (a `float` is an approximation using binary fractions, *not* a precise real number). But adjusting your loop a little this gives:

```
>>> for n in range(12000, -1, -1):
...     if (n ** (1.0/3)).is_integer():
...         print n
... 
27
8
1
0
```

which means that anything over 3 cubed, (including 10648) was missed out due to the aforementioned imprecision:

```
>>> (4**3) ** (1.0/3)
3.9999999999999996
>>> 10648 ** (1.0/3)
21.999999999999996
```

You'd have to check for numbers **close** to the whole number instead, or not use `float()` to find your number. Like rounding down the cube root of `12000`:

```
>>> int(12000 ** (1.0/3))
22
>>> 22 ** 3
10648
```

If you are using Python 3.5 or newer, you can use the [`math.isclose()` function](https://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.isclose) to see if a floating point value is within a configurable margin:

```
>>> from math import isclose
>>> isclose((4**3) ** (1.0/3), 4)
True
>>> isclose(10648 ** (1.0/3), 22)
True
```

For older versions, the naive implementation of that function (skipping error checking and ignoring infinity and NaN) as [mentioned in PEP485](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0485/#proposed-implementation):

```
def isclose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-9, abs_tol=0.0):
    return abs(a - b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)
```

Comment: Not knowing python, this sort of statement would make me nervous as it   seems to require perfect math to work in the real world.

Comment: @PeterM: The method indeed only returns `True` if there are no decimals at all. There may be a misunderstanding on the part of the OP about floating point arithmetic and precision,  of course.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah and one small slip in a floating point calculation and all of a sudden you have these little, unwanted decimals like 0.00000000000000000001

Comment: @PeterM: and in Python 2 the default representation will round to 16 digits; `1.0000000000000001` is displayed as `1.0`, in 3 the shortest string representation that produces the same value is shown.

Comment: Your `range(12000, -1, -1)` could be (imo, more cleanly) rewritten as `reversed(range(12000+1))`

Comment: @cs95: I don’t agree, and not really all that relevant to the question.

Comment: Sure it isn't relevant to the question, but it is to your answer since you're iterating in reverse. Using reversed is a bit more readable... Just my 2c.

Comment: This is great when you have a variable that you are sure is a float but I am surprised that `(1).is_integer()` raises `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_integer'`.

Comment: @Bill: `is_integer()` only applies to `float` because it tests the _value_, where `(3.14).is_integer()` is `False`, and `(3.0).is_integer()` while `True`. `int` is not a subclass of `float` nor is `is_integer()` part of the [`Real` abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Real).

Comment: Indeed but it might still be nice to have two equivalent methods that test to see if a value (int or float) is a whole number. Rather than having to use `isinstance(x, int) or x.is_integer()` or `float(x).is_integer()`. But that's okay, I can live with these solutions!

Answer (score 72):

We can use the modulo (%) operator. This tells us how many remainders we have when we divide x by y - expresses as `x % y`. Every whole number must divide by 1, so if there is a remainder, it must not be a whole number.

This function will return a boolean, `True` or `False`, depending on whether `n` is a whole number.

```
def is_whole(n):
    return n % 1 == 0
```

Comment: This is the better answer because it also works if `n` happens to be an integer. The accepted answer will fail in that case.

Answer (score 20):

You could use this:

```
if k == int(k):
    print(str(k) + " is a whole number!")
```

Comment: it fails for [larger numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26447472/4279) while `.is_integer()` continues to work.

Comment: Your link IMHO doesn't show that it doesn't work. It just shows that large floats lose precision. `is_integer` uses a similar method (`o = (floor(x) == x) ? Py_True : Py_False;`). But I agree, one should use `is_integer()` as it is much clearer.

Comment: yes. It just shows that large float may lose precision i.e., `large_float == large_int` may fail even if `large_float == float(large_int)`.

Comment: Do you have an example where it fails? I tested it with large numbers (e.g. the one in your link) and for them it works.

Comment: `123456789012345678901234567890.0 != 123456789012345678901234567890` but `123456789012345678901234567890.0 == float(123456789012345678901234567890)`

Comment: Yeah, but `k = 123456789012345678901234567890.0` then `k == int(k)` is True, which is the correct answer.

Comment: yes, your answer is technically correct. It is just misleading.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to loop or to check anything. Just take a cube root of 12,000 and round it down:

```
r = int(12000**(1/3.0))
print r*r*r # 10648
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use a [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operation for that.

```
if (n ** (1.0/3)) % 1 != 0:
    print("We have a decimal number here!")
```

Comment: if `n` is 6.2, 6.0, 6.12312412, we all have `"We have a decimal number here!"`?

Comment: @JayWong not sure how you loaded your test, but this works fine on my machine using Python3.7.

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
if x%1==0:
    print "is integer"
```

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't it be easier to test the cube roots? Start with 20 (20**3 = 8000) and go up to 30 (30**3 = 27000). Then you have to test fewer than 10 integers.

```
for i in range(20, 30):
    print("Trying {0}".format(i))
    if i ** 3 > 12000:
        print("Maximum integral cube root less than 12000: {0}".format(i - 1))
        break
```

Comment: Moreover, floats have round-off errors so that you can miss number when calculating if `n**(1/3)` is integer. For example on my computer ` 10648**(1/3)=21.999999999999996 ` instead of `22`: problem! With this answer's method there is no such problem. I think this is the only correct solution from a mathematic point of view (others solutions are Python-correct).

Answer (score 5):

The above answers work for many cases but they miss some. Consider the following:

```
fl = sum([0.1]*10)  # this is 0.9999999999999999, but we want to say it IS an int
```

Using this as a benchmark, some of the other suggestions don't get the behavior we might want:

```
fl.is_integer() # False

fl % 1 == 0     # False
```

Instead try:

```
def isclose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0):
    return abs(a-b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)

def is_integer(fl):
    return isclose(fl, round(fl))
```

now we get:

```
is_integer(fl)   # True
```

`isclose` comes with [Python 3.5+](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose), and for other Python's you can use this mostly equivalent definition (as mentioned in the corresponding [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0485/#proposed-implementation))

Comment: `math.fsum([0.1] * 10) == 1`

Answer (score 3):

Just a side info, `is_integer` is doing internally:

```
import math
isInteger = (math.floor(x) == x)
```

> Not exactly in python, but the cpython implementation is implemented as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
num = 1.9899
bool(int(num)-num)
#returns True
```

if it is True, It means it holds some value, hence not a whole number. Else

```
num = 1.0
bool(int(num)-num)
# returns False
```

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are good but a sure fire method would be

```
def whole (n):
     return (n*10)%10==0
```

The function returns True if it's a whole number else False....I know I'm a bit late but here's one of the interesting methods which I made...

Edit: as stated by the comment below, a cheaper equivalent test would be:

```
def whole(n):
    return n%1==0
```

Comment: This should be no functionally different than `n % 1 == 0`. In this case, you're doing two operations which is more expensive for a cheaper equivalent test.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def is_near_integer(n, precision=8, get_integer=False):
...     if get_integer:
...         return int(round(n, precision))
...     else:
...         return round(n) == round(n, precision)
...
>>> print(is_near_integer(10648 ** (1.0/3)))
True
>>> print(is_near_integer(10648 ** (1.0/3), get_integer=True))
22
>>> for i in [4.9, 5.1, 4.99, 5.01, 4.999, 5.001, 4.9999, 5.0001, 4.99999, 5.000
01, 4.999999, 5.000001]:
...     print(i, is_near_integer(i, 4))
...
4.9 False
5.1 False
4.99 False
5.01 False
4.999 False
5.001 False
4.9999 False
5.0001 False
4.99999 True
5.00001 True
4.999999 True
5.000001 True
>>>
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved, but I would like to propose an additional mathematical-based solution for funcies.

The benefit of this approach is that it calculates the whole number part of your number, which may be beneficial depending on your general task.

**Algorithm**:

- Decompose whole number part of your number its a sum of its decimals (e.g., `327=3*100+2*10+7*1`)
- take difference between calculated whole number and number itself
- decide whether difference is close enough to be considered an integer.

```py
from math import ceil, log, isclose

def is_whole(x: float) -> bool:
    n_digits = ceil(log(x,10)) # number of digits of decimals at or above ones
    digits = [(n//(10**i))%10 for i in range(n_digits)] # parse digits of `x` at or above ones decimal
    whole = 0 # will equal the whole number part of `x`
    for i in range(n_digits):
        decimal = 10**i
        digit = digits[i]
        whole += digit*decimal
    
    diff = whole - x
    return isclose(diff, 0.0)
```

> **NOTE:** the idea of parsing digits of a number was realized from [here](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/split-integer-into-digits-python/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`round`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) function to compute the value.

Yes in python as many have pointed when we compute the value of a cube root, it will give you an output with a little bit of error. To check if the value is a whole number you can use the following function:

```
def cube_integer(n):
    if round(n**(1.0/3.0))**3 == n:
        return True
    return False
```

But remember that [`int(n)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) is equivalent to [`math.floor`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.floor) and because of this if you find the `int(41063625**(1.0/3.0))` you will get 344 instead of 345.

So please be careful when using `int` withe cube roots.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
int(val) == val
```

It will give lot more precision than any other methods.

Comment: Can you give an example to back up the claim that "It will give lot more precision"?  This seems unfounded.