# x.is_integer() returns false when number is whole

Tags: python

Version: Python 2.7

I am trying to check if the number x, in this case 64, is a cube. I check if the root-cube of the number is an integer:

```
root3 = math.pow(64, (1/3.0))
print(root3)
print(root3.is_integer())
```

Which prints:

```
4.0
False
```

Which is wrong, since 4.0 is an integer. In comparison, using 4.0 directly:

```
print((4.0).is_integer())
```

Which prints `True`.

**How can I make sure the root cube of 64 is considered as a whole float?**

Comment: You didn't suspect an calculation round up issues?  `>>> root3` show 3.9999999999999996

Comment: IDLE tells me that `64 ** (1/3.0)` is `3.9999999999999996` (Python 3.4) and that's not an integer. Of course we know that the result should be `4.0` but floating point math can't be exact.

Comment: @Morno Check the dupe  [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586340/how-do-i-get-a-whole-number-as-a-result-for-a-cube-root). `root3` here will be `3.9999999999999996`. Another dupe can be [Is cube root integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23621833). A highly related read [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004)