# Filter integers in numpy float array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any built in function to discard integer and keep only float number in `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

input = np.array([0.0, 0.01, 1.0, 2.0, 2.001, 2.002])

desired_ouput = some_function(input)
# Expected ouput
# desired_output = np.array([0.01, 2.001, 2.002])
```

Comment: All values in that array are floats. "float" doesn't imply anything about the value being non-integer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mask with whether each element is equal to it as an integer.

```
arr = np.array([0.0, 0.01, 1.0, 2.0, 2.001, 2.002])
out = arr[arr != arr.astype(int)]
#np.array([0.01, 2.001, 2.002])
```

Answer (score 18):

I don't think so. My approach would be

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.0, 0.01, 1.0, 2.0, 2.001, 2.002])
mask = np.isclose(a, a.astype(int))

print(a[~mask])
#[ 0.01   2.001  2.002]
```

Comment: As a general rule always use `isclose` when comparing floats.  I'm not sure it's necessary here, but upvoted for good practice.

Comment: It's not a good practice to blindly follow what is called "good practice". `isclose`, depending on the source of these numbers, may actually be actively harmful.

Answer (score 6):

I know of no in-built function. But you can create one yourself:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([0.0, 0.01, 1.0, 2.0, 2.001, 2.002])

def remove_ints(arr):
    return arr[~(arr == arr.astype(int))]

res = remove_ints(A)

array([ 0.01 ,  2.001,  2.002])
```

Aside, you should not use a built-in class such as `input` as a variable name.

Answer (score 6):

I've always used `np.equal` with `np.mod`:

```
>>> A[~np.equal(np.mod(A, 1), 0)]
array([0.01 , 2.001, 2.002])
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have to much data (short list), maybe do not need `numpy`:

```
>>> i = [0.0, 0.01, 1.0, 2.0, 2.001, 2.002]
>>> a=[j for j in i if not j.is_integer()]
>>> a
['0.01', '2.001', '2.002']
```

Otherwise see Joe Iddon answer

Comment: The idea of scipy is to never use `for` for efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any builtin for this but you can filter those floats using:

```
filter(lambda x: int(str(x).split('.')[1]) != 0, input)
```

The lambda expression here checks if the decimal places are zero which I interpret as the number being an int.

Comment: precision is lost by converting to string. e.g `2.001` becomes `2.0009999999999999`.

Comment: What? I just tried replicating this but `[str(x) for x in input]` returned: `['0.0', '0.01', '1.0', '2.0', '2.001', '2.002']`? But even if i assume a loss of accuracy, it wouldn't change the results since '001' will not come out as 0 after the int cast, just like '00099999'.

Comment: It happend in my python. Actually these are indexes of pandas dataframe, so loss of precision mean, i can't get back values by apply `.loc` method.

Comment: Well, this would be very interesting indeed if you can find a way to replicate the effect...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question a while back: [Numpy: Check if float array contains whole numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35042128/2988730). The simplest way to mask fractions that I am currently aware of is

```
mask = ((input % 1) != 0)
```

You can then apply the mask directly with

```
output = input[mask]
```

It bothered me that there is no built-in function to determine the integerness of a float quickly, so I wrote a fast ufunc that provides the functionality of [`float.is_integer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) for numpy. You can download from [github](https://github.com/madphysicist/is_integer_ufunc) and compile if you're interested:

```
from is_integer_ufunc import is_integer

output = input[~is_integer(input)]
```

I'll see if the numpy community wants to consider adding something like that to the core library. The question seems to come up often enough to justify it.