# Is there a way to accept only the integer values after dividing a list?

Tags: python, list, numbers, integer, output

```
# Creating List of integers
List = [112, 966, 483, 807, 112, 693, 507, 712, 738, 605, 923, 112, 966, 679, 992, 29, 782, 780, 353, 392]

print("\nList of numbers: ")

print(List)

# Create Divide variable
myInt = 13

#List values divided by 13
newList = [x / myInt for x in List]

print("\nList Divided by 13")

print (newList)
```

I'm trying to make a new list now that is only of the sum of the division from my listed newList but i'm want only to keep the integers, How would I filter it out?

Or I guess what might be easier, if just listing how many numbers total can be divided by myInt and then output it as an integer?

Comment: Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52094533/filter-integers-in-numpy-float-array). It explains how to get only the integer values of an array (after your division) and then to get your result, you simply find the length of that filtered array.

Comment: Please work through a short tutorial on the modulus operator, `%`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo operator. **someNum % yourInt** will not give a remainder if it is divisible, therefore it will return 0. you can use that to filter.

```
if a % myInt == 0:
    # add to list
```

you can find more info here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-a-modulo-operator-in-python/ ( or just searching the modulo operator )

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check your `newList` value by using `if` in list

```
newList = [int(x / myInt) for x in List if x/myInt % 1 == 0 ]
```

The result will be `[39, 71, 60]`

Or you want each numbers integer part you can use

```
newList = [x // myInt for x in List ]
```

Take a look at [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193927/what-do-these-operators-mean).

Comment: Thanks, but trying to understand the last part, the if statement you're saying to put in, is the %1 ==0 making so anything that doesn't decimals is shown?

Comment: Decimal is not shown because `int(x / myInt)` remove the decimal part.
This line meaning is like
`
get each item in sequence in myList as x, and if x mod myInt equal to 0, convert it to int then put it in response(newList)`

If a values has decimal part it will be filtered out since %1 is not 0`

Comment: Awesome thanks for explaining! Was wondering on why that was and I haven't touched on modulus operations yet so I wasn't understanding some other post/ answers