# In Python 3.5.2, is it possible to remove the decimal place for integers whilst keeping it for floats

Tags: python

If I have a list of both integers and floats and I print it, is there a way to print the integers without a decimal place but keep it for the floats?

I created a game based on the cards in a deck where different cards have different values. The value of each card is then multiplied by either 2, 1.5, 1 or 0.5 based on the suit. This is done randomly. This process is repeated 10 times.

The code looks something like this:

```
Scores = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15]
Suits = [2, 1.5, 1, 0.5]
TScore = 0
for each in range(10):
Score = random.choice(Scores)
Suit = random.choice(Suits)
TScore = Score * Suit
print("Your score is {0}".format(TScore))
```

The console may print something like this:

> Your score is 12
>       Your score is 22.5
>       Your score is 18.0
>       Your score is 15
>       Your score is 30
>       Your score is 6.0
>       Your score is 6.0
>       Your score is 6.0
>       Your score is 12
>       Your score is 6

Is there a way to make sure that the integers are not followed by a decimal point?

Comment: How are you printing them? Are you sure they're not *both* floats? The fact that one could also be an integer can be tested with `float.is_integer`; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21583758/3001761

Comment: Please provide more details and enough data to enable others to help.

Comment: Those are both floats...

Comment: @jonrsharpe the question has been updated with the code

Comment: @adele code has been added.

Comment: There is a chance some of your outputs will be of type `int`, while some will be integer values of type `float`, while others will be non-integer rational numbers of type `float`.  I suggest you make _all_ the values in `Suits` into `floats` --- regardless of how you intend to display them later --- just to avoid the unexpected fun that mixing kind-of equivalent types can bring you.  (Exhibit A:  Some of your "integer" outputs have the trailing ".0" while some don't.)

Answer (score 4):

The `g` or `n` format `type` does this for you:

```
In [560]: for score in [4.0, 22.5]:
     ...:     print('Your score is {:n}'.format(score))
     ...:     
Your score is 4
Your score is 22.5
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Answer (score 1):

```
for score in [4.0, 22.5]:
    '''
    Modulo(%) pulls the remainder, if the number is a whole number
    dividing by 1 should always return 0.
    '''
    if score % 1 == 0:
        score = int(score)
    print(score)
```

For more information on modulo or other operators: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

In reference to jonrsharpe's comment above.

```
    if score.is_integer(): # a float.method returns true if the number is whole.
        score = int(score)
    print(score)
```

For more information on float.methods: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-float

Comment: if score.is_integer: # a float.method returns true if the number is whole.
        score = int(score)
    print(score)

it gives 4 if score is 4.0 or 4.8 in both the case

Comment: I apologize I entered a syntax error thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work in your case:

```
def removeDecimal(num):
        num1 = list(str(num))
        if(num1[-1]=='0'):      
                return int(num)
        else:
                return num

def main():
        score1 = 4.0
        score2 = 22.5
        print(removeDecimal(score1))    
        print(removeDecimal(score2))
if __name__=="__main__":
        main()
```

output for this is :

4

22.5