# Python3 division issues

Tags: integer, python-3.5, division

I am new to Python3 and facing this particular issue.
I want 6/2 to give an answer of 3 instead of 3.0, but at the same time i want 7/2 to give me 3.5
On using '//' it converts all the float values to integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the result has a value after the decimal point and cast to an integer or float depending on that.

```
num = a / b
if int(num) - num == 0:
    num = int(num)
else:
    num = float(num)
```

The second part is technically redundant, but I left it there for the sake of completeness.

This question is also a duplicate: [How to check if a float value is a whole number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583758/how-to-check-if-a-float-value-is-a-whole-number)