# How to get specific number of digits? Python

Tags: python, floating-point

How would I format my float digits so that there is always 7 digits no matter the direction?

The value could be any of the following but I always want 7 like below

```
0.0054233
1234567
123.1224
1.992923
```

The portion I have right now is

```
return "%.7f" % fd
```

How can I adjust that to get my desired output? or maybe link me to something similar I could try and read from..>?

Comment: For the number `1`, would you want `0000001`?  Or `1.000000`

Comment: Yea exactly, hence the dependability on the program you're coding.

Comment: But you are asking for a number to always have 7 digits? Unless I read that wrong...

Comment: Right, sorry, then I would prefer 1.000000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try if this can work for you:

```
n = 123.456789
decimals = 7 - len(str(int(n)))
print('{:.{prec}f}'.format(n, prec=decimals))
#=> 123.4568
```

The drawback is that it rounds up.

Comment: That's okay if it rounds up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context of the program, in my opinion... If you just want the numbers to the right to be 6 decimals, use:

```
"{:.6f}".format(whatevervar)
```

In other contexts maybe convert it to a string and use `len()` to evaluate the number of digits.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** Seeing your comments, I would recommend using a conditional to define what you are trying to do. When the number has no decimals (check this thread for how to do it: [How to check if a float value is a whole number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583758/how-to-check-if-a-float-value-is-a-whole-number) ) leave it as it is, when it has decimals, round it up with the code I posted above.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!