# the first if condition is work but the elif condition isn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

when i am trying to execute the code, the first `if` condition is work but the `elif` condition isn't. After the conditional statements, the `except` condition is working with no problem.

```
data = input("Type the number: ")
try:
    integer = int(data)
    decimal = float(data)
    if type(integer) == type(int()):
        for x in range(1,11,1):
            print("{} X {} = {}".format(integer,x,(integer*x)))
    elif type(decimal) == type(float()):  
        for x in range(1,11,1):
            print("{} X {} = {}".format(decimal,x,(decimal*x)))
except (TypeError,ValueError):
    print("Please type a number")
```

Comment: Why would it work? `integer` is always an integer, so why would that ever be false?

Comment: To make @Daniel Roseman comment clearer, any float can be converted to int: `type(int(1.2323)) == type(int())`, so `elif` is never executed.

Comment: Hi @Arsallan, if you found an valable answer please mark it as accepted, or add more precisions in your question otherwise :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert the input to `int` and `float`, just to one of them. Since `data` is `str` you can use `isdigit` to check if all the chars are digits and therefor it is `int`, or not. You also shouldn't compare types with `==`, use `isinstance`

```
data = input("Type the number: ")

try:
    if data.isdigit():
        number = int(data)
    else:
        number = float(data)

    if isinstance(number, int):
        for x in range(1, 11, 1):
            print("{} X {} = {}".format(number, x, (number * x)))
    elif isinstance(number, float):
        for x in range(1, 11, 1):
            print("{} X {} = {}".format(number, x, (number * x)))
except (TypeError, ValueError):
    print("Please type a number")
```

If you don't do anything withe the information what is the type, use one loop without check

```
data = input("Type the number: ")

try:
    if data.isdigit():
        number = int(data)
    else:
        number = float(data)
    for x in range(1, 11, 1):
        print("{} X {} = {}".format(number, x, (number * x)))
except (TypeError, ValueError):
    print("Please type a number")
```

You can also convert the input straight to `float`, but the results will look like `246.0` for ints.

Answer (score 0):

By reading your code, I believe you're trying to tell if the data the user entered is an integer or not.
To do so, refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583758/how-to-check-if-a-float-value-is-a-whole-number):

```py
data = input("Type the number: ")
try:
    decimal = float(data) # if data is not the representation of a float, this will raise an error
    if decimal.is_integer():
        integer = int(decimal)
        for x in range(1,11,1):
            print("{} X {} = {}".format(integer,x,(integer*x)))
    else:
        for x in range(1,11,1):
            print("{} X {} = {}".format(decimal,x,(decimal*x)))
except (TypeError,ValueError):
    print("Please type a number")
```

Another note about your code: `int(<anything>)` will either throw an error, or return an `int`. So your first condition is always `True`