# How to check if a list of floats adds up to a whole number?

Tags: python, list, math, floating-point, sum

I would like to find the sum of a list of floats and check if it is a whole number or not:

```py
l = [0.85, 0.85, 0.15, 0.15]
```

The sum of `l` is 2.0, obviously. But Python does not agree, due to [floating point limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken):

```py
> sum(l)
1.9999999999999998
```

Therefore my method of choice, `sum(l).is_integer()`, will return `False`.

What would be a better method to evaluate if lists sum to a whole number?

Comment: are you aware about floating point limitations?

Comment: The sum of `l` is 1?

Comment: relevant, not dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: This seems like a duplicat of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583758/how-to-check-if-a-float-value-is-a-whole-number

Comment: @RaySteam: This is not a duplicate of that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil How so? He basically knows how to sum, so what he needs is how to check if the result is a whole number. The marked answer basically tells the OP what he needs.

Comment: @RaySteam: The problem here is not to determine whether a number is an integer or to find an integer within certain bounds, both of which are issues in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583758/how-to-check-if-a-float-value-is-a-whole-number) but to determine whether the exact mathematical sum of a list of values is an integer. The fundamental problem is doing the exact mathematics in light of the rounding errors introduced by floating-point operations, which is not addressed in that question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `decimal` package.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> l = [Decimal(x) for x in ['0.85', '0.85', '0.15', '0.15']]
>>> s = sum(l)
>>> s
Decimal('2.00')
>>> s == int(s)
True
```

Comment: It's important to note that the `Decimal`s are created from strings, not the `float`s from the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) and the inbuilt [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function.

```
>>> from math import isclose  
>>> l = [0.85, 0.85, 0.15, 0.15]
>>> s = sum(l)
>>> isclose(s, round(s))
True
```

Comment: This is a good practical solution, but note that it breaks down in the case of large lists (e.g. `l = [0.05] * 1000000`) and gives false positives (e.g. `l = [0.0000000001]`)

Comment: As I said, it's a good solution, but I wanted to note this since this is a fundamental limitation of floating point.  Changing `rel_tol` can only change which edge cases fail.

Answer (score 2):

When you need exact arithmetic, the best solution is to work with integers only.  In this case you could round each of your inputs to 2 or 3 decimal places for the check.

```
l = [0.85, 0.85, 0.15, 0.15]
number_of_places = 3
multiplier = 10 ** number_of_places
>>> sum(int(round(x*multiplier)) for x in l)
2000
>>> sum(int(round(x*multiplier)) for x in l) % multiplier == 0
True
```

Comment: Not applicable in all cases, but definitely a good way to do it when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Apart Decimal, you can also use the fractions module, which will enable handling arbitrary denominators like:

```
from fractions import Fraction
print(Fraction(1,3) + Fraction(4,7) + Fraction(2,21))
```

Also works with `Fraction('0.85') + Fraction('0.15')` or `Fraction('2/6')`.

Note that the result of adding Fractions is a Fraction, eventually with denominator == 1, so instead of testing  `is_integer()`, you have to replace with a denominator check, or with equality of int conversion:

```
collection = [Fraction(each) for each in ['0.85', '0.85', '0.15', '0.15']]
sum = sum(collection)
print(sum.denominator == 1)
print(int(sum) == sum)
```

In some languages including Smalltalk, Fractions are automatically reduced to Integer when denominator is 1, making the code a bit less brittle...

```
^((1/3) + (4/7) + (2/21)) isInteger
```